# LaTeX project file system structure and Ouput dir on TeXworks

Tags: texworks, latex-misc

I am writing a report that contain numerous sub items. For better organizing the report, it is broken in many smaller pieces (around 60), this is done to make it easier for to work distributed with other folks and to have a quick full change history of each part on svn (today is only me, but soon more people will join the project). As I'm new to LaTeX, I wonder if the file structure I am using makes the development better. I am using the following folder/files structure (based on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/General_Guidelines#Project_structure):

```
/mainFile.tex
/tex/chapter1.tex
/tex/chapter2.tex
/tex/chapter3/chapter3.tex
/tex/chapter3/chapter3section1.tex
/tex/chapter3/chapter3section2.tex
/...
/img
/reportclass.cls
/biblio.bib
```

The image folder keeps all images. I would like to hear from you about my approach and which folder structure you usually have on your LaTeX projects.
Another question is, when it compiles, all aux, blg, bbl, toc and so files are built on project root folder. Searching here, I found that I could change the -output-directory=DIR on latex command line. However, I use TeXworks that comes with MiKTeX for editing and generating the pdf output. Does any one know how to set that option on TeXworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the last question:

Go to Edit --> Preferences, and look under the Typesetting tab. Here, all the different tools for typesetting is listed. You can edit existing tools, adding more arguments, or you can create your own. It might be better to create a new, so you don't have to change back for other projects.

Comment: @Tobjorn T. Excellent! By looking there, I found out it was using texify.exe and added the option -c what solved the issue! Any comment about the other subject? Thanks.