# LaTeX equivalent to R's ProjectTemplate package?

Tags: folders

The post [LaTeX project file system structure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11360/latex-project-file-system-structure-and-ouput-dir-on-texworks) has helped me a lot in organizing my LaTeX projects. This got me the thinkin': the R package [ProjectTemplate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ProjectTemplate/index.html) allows the user to build an R project directory structure with template files according to best practices.

Q: Is there anything out there equivalent to this for LaTex?

Quick searches of the web have returned nothing. If there really isn't any equivalent out there, I suppose it wouldn't be terribly difficult to build my own default structure to copy from.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're looking for?

Comment: @TH: I'm looking for a template latex project directory structure with template `.tex`, `.cls`, etc., files all following best practices. If nothing like that exists, I'll just start building my own.

Comment: is your question about the _content_ of the `.tex`, `.cls`, etc. files, or is it about where to put them. --- By the way, most of my LaTeX projects don't include any `.cls` file, only `.tex` files using standard classes and packages.

Comment: I'd be interested in this package as well.  Did you ever find something that meets your needs here?

Comment: @AaronMassey: Nope. And, starting a new job, haven't had time to put one together either :( I just created a template directory for myself and use that.