# Using subfiles package with .sty files

Tags: folders, subfiles

Following the [Project Structure Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/General_Guidelines#Project_structure) and [Subfiles Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Multiple_files#Subfiles_package), I've built the following project structure:

```
./mydocument.tex
./mystyle.sty
./tex/mysubfile.tex
./img/
```

`mydocument.tex` looks like:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\subfile{./tex/mysubfile.tex} 
\end{document}
```

`mystyle.sty` looks like:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\usepackage{subfiles}
% other packages
% command declarations
```

`mysubfile.tex` looks like:

```
\documentclass[../mydocument.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
% stuff goes here.
\end{document}
```

I'm using (1) the `subfiles` package because I'd like to compile `mysubfile.tex` by itself and (2) `mystyle.sty` because I'd like to modularize this project a bit and split package and command declarations into their own `.sty` file. **The problem** is that when I try and compile `mysubfile.tex` by itself it can't "see" `mystyle.sty`.

Q: Is there some way I can still satisfy (1), (2), and the project structure outlined above and get things working? Some sort of option or command in the `subfiles` package?

I've tried: (1) moving `mystyle.sty` to different directories, (2) moving the `subfiles` declaration `\usepackage{subfiles}` to different parts of the document, (3) checking the `subfiles` documentation. All no dice.

I suppose that the second best option would be to stick all project files in the same folder and get rid of my `.\tex` folder. At least then, I can get things to compile. But I'd rather not sacrifice the project structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to put your other `.tex`-files into subdirectories. I don't know the `subfiles` package, but I can recommend you the `standalone` package for this (I should mention here that I wrote it, so I'm biased).
Put all required packages into the subfiles and compile them as normal just use `standalone` as class. The real class can be given by the `class` option and defaults to `article`. In the main document load the `standalone` *package*, maybe with the `subpreambles` option to include the preambles from the subfiles to the main file.

```
% Main file
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\input{mysubfile.tex}
\end{document}


% mysubfile.tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
% stuff
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Martin: It looks like the `subfiles` package does something very similar. One thing I like about the `subfiles` package is that it allows me to put sub-documents in folders different from the main document. I can just pass the location of the main document as an option to `subfiles` package declaration.

Comment: @Martin: I supposed I don't _need_ to put other `.tex` files in sub-folders, but it is recommended in a number locations like, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6145/is-there-any-way-to-build-a-latex-document-from-a-parent-directory), [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/General_Guidelines#Project_structure), and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11360/latex-project-file-system-structure-and-ouput-dir-on-texworks). Plus, I just like the structure. Ahh well, I guess something will have to give.

Comment: @Martin: The other thing I like about the `subfiles` package is that you don't need to include extra package declarations in your sub-files.

Comment: @brianjd: Yes, its seems that `subfiles` and `standalone` are doing something very similar just look at the preamble-sharing from two different sites. What I like on `standalone` is that you don't have to update your main preamble every time you include one of your subfiles! IMHO the subfiles are independent from the main file because they are used in many different main files (digest, paper, presentation of that paper, thesis). I can freely mix my subfiles (holding mostly diagrams) and `standalone` makes sure all required packages are loaded.

Comment: @brianjd: Also you can load files from other directories with `standalone` and I agree that different types of files might be placed in different directories. I normally put my figures into `figures/`. What I don't get is why put other `.tex` files in different directory **by default** as the main `.tex` file? I also put `.tex` holding diagrams into a *central* directory and use the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable to a point `latex` there. No package option required. Putting all of these files into a `texmf` tree might be even better.

Comment: @brianjd: About the three links you give: The first only seems to discuss the *possibility*, not if it is recommended. The 2nd is a wikibook with IMHO questionable quality ([Caramdir modified it yesterday](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/587351#587351) because of that) and the 3rd links simply references the 2nd one. I put my different thesis chapters also into different subdirectories but I don't have a `tex` directory.

Comment: @Martin. Yes, I'm seeing your point. Splitting `.tex` files into separate directories only seems to increase the chance of bugs (which I've had). But, I will say that being able to split your `.tex` sub-files into a `/tex` sub-directory and keeping a `main.tex` up in the main project directory is nice in that it discourages an unknowledgeable user from mucking around with the sub-files and to just compile from the `main.tex`. Minor point I suppose.

Answer (score 21):

I have a clever workaround to do this with the `subfiles` package. Just slightly modify your project structure:

```
./main/mydocument.tex
./main/mystyle.sty
./tex/mysubfile.tex
./img/
```

Then, always call files starting with `..`, for example `../main/mystyle.sty`. This same path is correct whether you're starting from `./main/mydocument.tex` or `./tex/mysubfile.tex`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `mystyle.sty` in multiple documents, you might consider putting it in a place that is searchable by TeX.  Usually, this is the output of the command `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` (more precisely, the `tex/latex/` subdirectory of that directory).  Once you put the file there, you should run the command `texhash`.  Then, `kpsewhich myfile.sty` should print the path to the file.  After doing this `\usepacakge{mystyle}` will work in all your LaTeX documents, without needing a copy of `mystyle.sty` in the same directory as the `.tex` file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's a good idea. It'll definitely work. But I (1) don't want the `mystyle` package to be visible to other projects, (2) don't want the `tex/latex` folder becoming clogged with a bunch of my project-specific classes, and (3) want all my project files in one folder so that they can easily be `tar`'d and emailed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the internal macro `\input@path` as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24827/34384.

You just need to add:

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{../}}
\makeatother
```

at the top of `mysubfile.tex`.

However, a problem may occur if you have two files with the same name in `.` and `./tex`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just last week using the **subfile package** . If you have a file structure that includes different directories you'll often find addressing errors such as "file mychapter.tex not found" or "mystyle.sty not found". In order to avoid this problems always use the full path to each file, specially to the main.tex, since the style files are often in the same directory that the main.tex.

Here's the example you gave previously

```
/home/username/Documents/report/mydocument.tex
/home/username/Documents/report/mystyle.sty
/home/username/Documents/report/tex/mysubfile.tex
/home/username/Documents/report/img/
```

mydocument.tex looks like:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\subfile{/home/username/Documents/report/tex/mysubfile.tex} 
\end{document}
```

mystyle.sty looks like:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\usepackage{subfiles}
% other packages
% command declarations
```

mysubfile.tex looks like:

```
\documentclass[/home/username/Documents/report/mydocument.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
% stuff goes here.
\end{document}
```

It all goes in the logic followed by LaTeX to look for files: When you compile "mysubfile.tex" the reference directory will be */home/username/Documents/report/tex*. It will look for the preambule in the file mydocument.tex located in the directory */home/username/Documents/report/*. mydocument.tex will look for mystyle.sty located in the reference directory: */home/username/Documents/report/tex*

By the way, you can put the \usepackage{subfiles} into mydocument.tex. It might be easier to load this package in your main.tex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some people may find this helpful, however such full paths are not a portable solution, which others may need.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the problem with full paths. Although it is the best way to avoid problems in bash, is not that nice in LaTeX. I don't understand what you mean by portable. Full paths solved my problem with nesting directories while making subfiles.

Comment: By "portable" I mean if you move your code to another machine or account then you will have to rewrite the paths before it will work.

Comment: Well.. When you compile a main or a subfile, the directory you are in becomes the "reference directory". Meaning that if you have a file structure with nested directories the "reference directory" will not be the same. So, the relative address of each `subfile.tex` and `style.sty` (as well as that of the `main.tex`) will change. This is a very common problem in bash, chaning the path to your files doesn't make your code less portable. If you require to compile your document in multiple locations, use specialized services to keep the structure of your files.

Comment: I was wondering Andrew Swann, Is there a way to "declare the path" in LaTeX ? In bash we usually create a variable with the path. This way the path only needs to be "updated" once everytime you change computer|session|folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a suitable operating system you can create a symbolic link from `./tex/` to the style files in the parent directory.

For example,

`ln -s ~/path/to/document/mystyle.tex ~/path/to/document/tex/`