# Local texmf tree vs. `TEXINPUTS`

Tags: texmf, texinputs

[Integrating Local Additions](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html) provides a nice explanation of how to manipulate `TEXINPUTS` or register a local texmf tree.

Q: When integrating local additions, is there a reason to prefer one approach over the other?

I'm guessing that `TEXINPUTS` is just regarded as the quick and dirty approach while registering a local texmf tree may be a better idea if you have a lot of files within a logical directory structure to which `latex` needs to be pointed.

If I'm missing something here I'd love to hear about it :)

This question is a follow-up to my post [Texmf tree with MikTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12338/texmf-tree-with-miktex-vista32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX itself uses TEXINPUTS and it can cause an error if it is also set by the user. An almost secure way is to use a local texmf tree. With MiKTeX you can have several of them. For Linux you have TEXMF, TEXMFLOCAL and TEXMFHOME. The latter do not need a `texhash´ command, it is searched recursively by TeX.

Comment: I have never heard of using TEXINPUTS causing trouble if used correctly. It is *intended* to be used by the user, surely? (And by used correctly, I mean typically with a trailing colon, to insert the directories spesified by the `texmf.conf` file(s) at the end.)

Comment: I have several TeXLive versions and ConTeXt minimals installed and run permanent into trouble when using TEXINPUTS and switching between ConTeXt and PDFTeX

Comment: If you say so, but I remain skeptical in the absense of more detailed evidence.

Comment: I know that on MikTeX 2.8 `TEXINPUTS` is not even initially defined. The user must define it and initialize it to the path of interest. I played with it---adding, deleting, etc. No issues so far.

Comment: The MikTeX documentation specifically states that TEXINPUTS is used to resolve \input. That being the case it has no connection to 'using a local texmf tree'. The document linked to by the OP, has itself a link to the ref I mentioned.

Comment: @hsmyers: Try setting `TEXINPUTS` and then run a context file and you'll see what I mean!

Answer (score 6):

TEXINPUTS is easier and works best for ad-hoc files.  If you use the same files with different jobs, and particularly if you have other kinds of files such as fonts, you are best off using a Texmf tree because you do not need to manage environment variables and the Texlive command-line tools understand the Texmf tree better.