# List of People analog to Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, database

In my document I emphasize names that are mentioned and now I want to provide some additional information about them in an appendix. Currently I do something like:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIXGeneral}
\def\name#1{{\texorpdfstring{\smaller\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
    Look at the works of \name{Alexandrov} and \name{Atkinson}.
    \clearpage
    \begin{section}*{Index of People}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \name{Alexandrov}: Па́вел Серге́евич Алекса́ндров (Pavel Sergeyevich Alexandrov), \mbox{1896-05-07} – \mbox{1982-11-16}
            \item \name{Atkinson}: Frederick Valentine Atkinson, \mbox{1916-01-25} – \mbox{2002-11-13}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{section}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to keep the information about the people in some database file like it is done with bibliographies and have it automatically formatted?  Are there any tools available or can it be done with `bibtex`?

JLDiaz's answer seems like a good point to start. To be a bit more concrete, the data file should look something like:

```
@person{alexandrov,
    name = {Па́вел Серге́евич Алекса́ндров},
    latin = {Pavel Sergeyevich Alexandrov},
    birthdate = {1896-05-07},
    deathdate = {1982-11-16}
}
```

And it may certainly happen, that more fields will be added (e.g. profession, places of birth and death, nationality). So it seems whether I am using `bibtex` or the `gloss` package, I have to define my own style file. What is the difference between those two approaches?

As for defining the custom entry type I found [Biblatex and custom bibtex entries - is it possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15597/biblatex-and-custom-bibtex-entries-is-it-possible), but the explanation there does not seem well structured / complete and possibly outdated. Maybe somebody can elaborate on that.

Comment: Perhaps you could keep the information in a `.csv` database and use the `datatool` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `datatool` package is designed for this sort of thing.  You could even use it with a `.bib` file if you liked.  See the (very detailed) package documentation for further details.  I'll give a simpler version.

Imagine you have a file `namedb.csv` that looks like this:

```
"Name","Latin","Birthdate","Deathdate"
"Па́вел Серге́евич Алекса́ндров","Pavel Sergeyevich Alexandrov","1896--05--07","1982--11--16"
"Па́вел","Pavel","1896--01--01","1982--01--01"
```

Then you could do an itemize environment or (better, I think) a (long)table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertineotf}% don't have your STIX font
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,datatool}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\parindent0pt
% ------------------------------8<------------------------------ %
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{namedb}{namedb.csv}%

% --- Itemize version
\begin{itemize}
\DTLforeach{namedb}{%
% "Name","Latin","Birthdate","Deathdate"
\name=Name,%
\latinname=Latin,%
\birthdate=Birthdate,%
\deathdate=Deathdate% pay attention to spacing in this command
}%
{%
 \item \name: \latinname, \birthdate\,---\,\deathdate
}
\end{itemize}

% --- Longtable version (for tables longer than one page)
\DTLdisplaylongdb[%
% caption={Index of People},%
 label={peopleindex},%
 contcaption={Index of People (continued)},% <-- if more than one page
 foot={\em Continued on next page},%
 lastfoot={},%
 ]{namedb}

\end{document}
```

A lot more could be done, in fact.  But as I don't know your precise needs, I'm going to keep it simple.

Comment: When using the `csv` file this seems like a good approach. But it looks like the `databib` part of `datatools` does not allow arbitrary entry types and relies on `bibtex` to be run with a special `databib` style file. Thus I will now try to keep a database in `bibtex` format, so I may later use `biblatex 2.0`, and convert it with a script to a `csv` file. That in turn can be processed by `datatool` as you described. When it works I will probably accept this answer. (Unfortunately you have to choose exactly one.)

Comment: @canaaerus -- Well pick the answer that works for you.  (Biber+biblatex is the way of the future, after all!)

Answer (score 19):

You might want to look at biblatex 2.0 with biber 1.0 as the bibtex replacement backend. The new `\DeclareDatamodel` functionality will allow you to define such entries in your .bib files and as long as you write a bit of style code to format them, you could then print such a list with a `\printbibliography` filter. Here is a rough example which works - I haven't fine-tuned the font switching etc.

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@PERSON{alexandrov,
  NAME      = {Па́вел Серге́евич Алекса́ндров},
  LATINNAME = {Pavel Sergeyevich Alexandrov},
  DATE      = {1896-05-07/1982-11-16},
} 
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{person.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{person}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name]{name, latinname}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[person]{
name,
latinname,
day,
endday,
month,
endmonth,
year,
endyear}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[datamodel=person,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelname{shortauthor,author,shorteditor,editor,translator,name,latinname}

\newbibmacro*{personname}{%
  \printnames{name}%
  \ifnameundef{latinname}
    {}
    {\addspace\mkbibparens{\printnames{latinname}}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{person}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{personname}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printdate
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{alexandrov}
\printbibliography[title=People,type=person]
\end{document}
```

[image: Datamodel example]

Comment: That sounds nice. Unfortunately those things are not available on `Gentoo` stable yet. I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: They will both be in TexLive 2012 as updates very shortly, or you can just get them from SourceForge.

Comment: I have updated the answer with example code showing how to do this with biblatex 2.0/biber 1.0

Comment: Great, I'll try it as soon as I have the software installed. One other thing still: why does `\cite` give the output "Алекса́ндров 1896-1982"; maybe because of `datatype=name`?

Comment: Because `\cite` prints labelname and I included `name` in the labelname search using `\DeclareLabelname`. You could change this or redefine `\cite` if you need something else.

Answer (score 6):

Technically, what you are asking for is a list of pairs *name-definition*, so it can be done with any tool to manage glossaries.

But since you mention the use of `bibtex`, I think you can be interested in package [gloss](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/gloss.html), which stores the pairs *name-definition* in a `.bib` file and uses `bibtex` to extract the list lf names referenced in the latex document.