# Can biblatex parse a name string directly instead of loading from a file?

Tags: biblatex

I've inherited a large, highly customized project for building a handbook for an academic conference. Among the many, many macros is the following:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citefullauthornames}{%
  \boolfalse{citetracker}%
  \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
  \usebibmacro{prenote}%
}{\indexnames{labelname}%
  \printnames[fullauthornames]{labelname}%
}{\multicitedelim}{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

where "fullauthornames" is a name format that does just what you'd expect. This code is then called as `\citefullauthornames{bibtex-identifier}`, where `bibtex-identifier` maps to an entry from one of the bibtex files loaded earlier in the project, presumably pulling out the "Author" field and parsing the names.

My question is, is it possible to get biblatex to parse a name string directly, so that I could write something like the following?

```
\citefullauthornames{Newton, John and Curie, Marie and Einsten, Albert and Feynman, Richard}
```

I've spent some time in the biblatex documentation but am a bit overwhelmed.

(As to why I'd want to do this, there are occasions where I just want a string of names parsed, printed correctly, and added to the index, and don't need any of the other information present in a bibtex file).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I doubt very much that this is possible. Of course, you could write code to do it, but I don't think that `biblatex` provides that code because `biblatex` doesn't parse the author strings at all. It doesn't read your `.bib` file. It writes the `.bcf` file and reads the `.bbl` file. The `.bbl` file is produced by parsing the `.bcf` and `.bib` files but that parsing is done by an external programme - `biber` or `bibtex`. `biblatex` doesn't even read the `.bib` file but puts e.g. `<bcf:datasource type="file" datatype="bibtex">x.bib</bcf:datasource>` in the `.bcf` for `biber`.

Comment: Personally, if I wanted to do something like this, I'd consider a `.csv` and something like `datatool` or `csvsimple` (though I'm not sure if that'd be the best approach).  There's also the `nameauth` package. However, I've never used it because it seemed like serious overkill for my own needs, so I can't say anything useful about it beside the fact that it exists.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [List of People analog to Bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62982/35864). From what I've seen so far, this is not directly possible. The names are parsed by the back-end (Biber/BibTeX), so you would have to find a way to let the back-end parse the names from within your `.tex` file. Your easiest way out is probably just a dummy entry for the authors much in the same vein to the link above.

Comment: You could write the names to some tempory bib-file, call biber to process them as always and then use them.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It sounds like this isn't possible, so I will just write out dummy entries in a bibtex file and load from that. Thanks for the help understanding how this works.

Comment: @cfr Seems like your comment helped the OP figure out a solution. Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @moewe Well, OK. Thanks. Rather a negative answer... :(.

Comment: @cfr Thanks! It might be rather negative, but it still suggests a viable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, this is not possible because `biblatex` does not parse the author strings at all. Instead, `biber` or `bibtex` does the parsing.

`biblatex` does not read your `.bib` file. It writes the `.bcf` file and reads the `.bbl` file. An external programme - `biber` or `bibtex` - parses the `.bcf` and `.bib` files and produces the `.bbl` file. `biblatex` doesn't even read the `.bib` file. What it does with the information provided about bibliographical resources in your document is to put things like the following into the `.bcf`:

```
<bcf:datasource type="file" datatype="bibtex">x.bib</bcf:datasource>
```

`biber` or `bibtex` uses this information, along with the other information in the `.bcf`, to create the `.bbl` file.

So to use the parsing facilities, you have to use the programme which provides them i.e. `biber` or `bibtex`, and that means providing the relevant information in a format that programme can digest. Unfortunately, your `.tex` file is likely to cause either of these programmes severe indigestion.

So the best option is almost certainly 'dummy' `.bib` entries, as [you suggest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242193/can-biblatex-parse-a-name-string-directly-instead-of-loading-from-a-file?noredirect=1#comment577896_242193). Either you can create these separately or you can have them automatically written out when you compile your main `.tex` file, as [Ulrike Fischer suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242193/can-biblatex-parse-a-name-string-directly-instead-of-loading-from-a-file?noredirect=1#comment576266_242193).