# How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?

Tags: biblatex

The title is pretty self-explanatory.
I need something similar to [Add new field to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65374/17423), but for completely new entry types.
(IIUC, the linked just shuffles one type onto another.)

I'm trying to define a `@stackexchange` type where I can cite StackExchange questions:

```
@stackexchange{se:l3help,
  sitekey = {tex},
  % sitetopic = {\TeX, \LaTeX, Con\TeX t, and related typesetting systems},
  askid   = {45838},
  title   = {What can \textit{I} do to help the \LaTeX3 Project},
  askdate = {2012/02/26}
}
```

where `id` must match the regexp `[0-9]+`, `asked` is a date, and `sitekey` provides a hard-coded mapping to the appropriate `sitetopic` when available.
If `sitekey` isn't available, then `sitetopic` is required.  If `sitetopic` is supplied, then it overwrites the mapping from `sitekey`.  `id`, `title`, and `asked` are all required.

If there are any other fields you think should be included, feel free; I tried to pare down the data type only to the 'special' ones.  I would hope that this Q can cover most of the bases for different ways fields can act.

#### MWE (Adapted per comments)

```
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@stackexchange{se:l3help,
    sitetopic = {tex},
    title   = {What can \textit{I} do to help the \LaTeX3 Project},
    askdate = {2012/02/26},
    askid   = {45838},
    askp    = {Brent Longorough},
    askerid = 344,
    ansp    = {Frank Mittelbach},
    anspid  = 10109,
    ansdate = {2012/03/01},
    ansid   = 46427
  }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{stackexchange.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{stackexchange}
\DeclareDatamodelFields{
  sitekey,
  sitetopic,
  askdate,
  askedit,
  askid,
  askp,
  askpid,
  ansp,
  anspid,
  ansid,
  ansdate,
  ansedit}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[stackexchange]{
  sitekey,
  sitetopic,
  askdate,
  askedit,
  askid,
  askp,
  askpid,
  ansp,
  anspid,
  ansid,
  ansdate,
  ansedit,
  title}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=stackexchange,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangequestion}{%
  \mkbibquote{\printfield{title}}
  \mkbibparens{\printfield{askid}}
  \addperiod
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangeask}{%
  Asked \mkbibdatelong{\printfield{askdate}}%
    \iffieldundef{askedit}{}{ \mkbibparens{edited \mkbibdatelong{\printfield{askedit}}}}%
  by
  \printfield{askp} \mkbibparens{\printfield{askpid}}
  \addperiod
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangeans}{%
  Answered \mkbibdatelong{\printfield{ansdate}}%
    \iffieldundef{ansedit}{}{ \mkbibparens{edited \mkbibdatelong{\printfield{ansedit}}}}%
  by
  \printfield{ansp} \mkbibparens{\printfield{anspid}}
  \addperiod
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangesite}{%
  \printfield{sitetopic}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{stackexchange}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangequestion}%
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeask}%
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeans}%
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangesite}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}

\cite{se:l3help}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Throws a `Missing \endcsname` error, likely caused by misuse of `\usebibmacro`.

Comment: I think you want to look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62995/8528).  It has a simple example of how to use `\DeclareDatamodel*` commands, which you would then pair with `\newbibmacro`s and so forth.

Comment: What exactly would you like an answer to this question look like that the answer jon linked cannot give you? ([Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114207/35864), we did not define a new entry type, but heavily modified an existing one; that might also be of interest to you.)

Comment: @jon I'll take a look at those and see if I can get a working solution.  Thanks for the links `:)`

Comment: @moewe To be perfectly honest I never found the linked questions. I'm going to try and get it working with this new information; hopefully nothing has changed with the way BibLaTeX/Biber does things in two years.

Comment: @All: See edits.

Comment: Related [Creating Entry in Bibtex for Executive Orders](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98512/35864)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

*The answer is now updated for the date handling in newer `biblatex` versions >= 3.6, lots of what had to be done manually before will now be done automatically. Check the edit history for earlier versions.*

This is quite a full-on question, but I will try to answer it anyway. This answer mainly deals with the *bibliography* output. For citations additional modifications and configurations might be necessary, but what needs to be done strongly depends on the used style, there is no universal answer. For `numeric` citation styles the example below will of course work without further modification.

### Declare new fields, and the new entry types and their fields

First, when declaring the data model, we need to make sure `biblatex` actually knows the type of the fields/lists we declare (this is done via the optional argument to `\DeclareDatamodelFields`). You can read much more about this in §4.5.4 *Data Model Specification*, p. 212 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

There are two main types for entry field: `field` and `list`. `field`s usually hold one value, while `list`s can hold more items separated by an `and` in the `.bib` file (see also §2.2.1 *Data Types*, p. 15).

I declared the `sitekey` and `sitetopic` to be literal fields (such as the `title` field).
`askp` and `ansp` are clearly name lists (even though in this context the list will probably only ever hold one item).
A lot of the fields you are asking for seem to revolve about dates, so there are `askdate`, `ansdate`, `askeditdate`, `anseditdate` and their `datepart`s (which will be created automatically, but they still need to be added to `\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields` manually).
Finally, I decided the `id`s should be verbatim fields.

```
\begin{filecontents}{stackexchange.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{stackexchange}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  sitekey,
  sitetopic,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  askp,
  ansp,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  askdate,
  ansdate,
  askeditdate,
  anseditdate}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=verbatim]{
  askid,
  askpid,
  anspid,
  ansid,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[stackexchange]{
  sitekey,
  sitetopic,
  askid,
  askp,
  askpid,
  ansp,
  anspid,
  ansid,
  askyear,
  askmonth,
  askday,
  ansyear,
  ansmonth,
  ansday,
  askedityear,
  askeditmonth,
  askeditday,
  ansedityear,
  anseditmonth,
  anseditday,
  title}
\end{filecontents}
```

The `\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields` just makes those fields relevant to `@stackexchange` known to that entry type.

### Declare new bibliography strings (if necessary)

We also want to display words like 'asked' and 'answered', instead of hard-coding them, localisation with `.lbx` files is the way to go. This is only necessary if you wish to include strings in the output. It is not necessary to include a string for each field you define. The fact that the name of some bibstrings coincides with the name of some fields is purely accidental. There is no requirement to define bibstrings for certain field types.

The most complete way to define new strings is by means of an `.lbx` file, because that method allows you to define long and short forms of the strings. You can also define new strings directly in the preamble, but then you can only give one form that is used as short and long version.

Our new localisation file `english-stack.lbx` inherits everything from `english.lbx` but adds `asked`, `answered` and `edited` as bibstrings.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{english-stack.lbx}
  \ProvidesFile{english-stack.lbx}[2014/05/07 english with additions for stackexchange]
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
  \NewBibliographyString{asked,answered,edited}
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit   = {english},
    asked     = {{asked}{asked}},
    answered  = {{answered}{answered}},
    edited    = {{edited}{edited}},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
```

We have to tell `biblatex` to use that language definition

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-stack}
```

### Defining the bibliography output

Then finally, we can go on to define the bibliography driver. The bibliography driver is the main definition that decides how the entry is printed in the bibliography. A bibliography driver typically consists of calls to several bibliography macros as well as calls to punctuation and printing commands.

#### Field formats

Field formats define the formatting of each printed field. We avoid hard-coding anything and use the macros provided by `biblatex`.

So instead of wrapping `\printfield{title}` in `\mkbibquote`, we define the field format to do so.
We use `\setunit` for punctuation and `\bibstring`s in lieu of hard-coded words.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[stackexchange]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{askpid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}
    
\DeclareFieldFormat{anspid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}
    
\DeclareFieldFormat{askid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}
    
\DeclareFieldFormat{ansid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}
```

As an added bonus, the `id` fields now link to the proper stackexchange site.

```
\newbibmacro*{stackexchangequestion}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{askid}%
}
```

#### Bibliography macros

Bibliography macros can be used to compartmentalise the output definitions.

No formatting should be applied to the `\printfield` commands, formatting is dealt with by `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

```
\newbibmacro*{stackexchangeask}{%
  \bibstring{asked}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printaskdate%
  \iffieldundef{askedityear}%
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \bibstring{edited}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printaskeditdate}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \bibstring{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{askp}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{askpid}%
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangeans}{%
  \bibstring{answered}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printansdate%
  \iffieldundef{ansedityear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \bibstring{edited}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printanseditdate}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \bibstring{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{ansp}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{anspid}%
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangesite}{%
  \printfield{sitetopic}}
```

#### Bibliography driver

The driver defines the final output structure. Usually a driver makes heavy use of bibmacros, but it need not do that.

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{stackexchange}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangequestion}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeask}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeans}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangesite}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

### MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@stackexchange{se:l3help,
  sitetopic = {tex},
  title   = {What can \textit{I} do to help the \LaTeX3 Project},
  askdate = {2012-02-26},
  askid   = {45838},
  askp    = {Brent Longorough},
  askpid  = {344},
  ansp    = {Frank Mittelbach},
  anspid  = {10109},
  ansdate = {2012-03-01},
  ansid   = {46427},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents}{stackexchange.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{stackexchange}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  sitekey,
  sitetopic,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  askp,
  ansp,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  askdate,
  ansdate,
  askeditdate,
  anseditdate}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=verbatim]{
  askid,
  askpid,
  anspid,
  ansid,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[stackexchange]{
  sitekey,
  sitetopic,
  askid,
  askp,
  askpid,
  ansp,
  anspid,
  ansid,
  askyear,
  askmonth,
  askday,
  ansyear,
  ansmonth,
  ansday,
  askedityear,
  askeditmonth,
  askeditday,
  ansedityear,
  anseditmonth,
  anseditday,
  title}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=stackexchange,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{english-stack.lbx}
  \ProvidesFile{english-stack.lbx}[2014/05/07 english with additions for stackexchange]
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
  \NewBibliographyString{asked,answered,edited}
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit   = {english},
    asked     = {{asked}{asked}},
    answered  = {{answered}{answered}},
    edited    = {{edited}{edited}},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-stack}

\DeclareFieldFormat[stackexchange]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{askpid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}
    
\DeclareFieldFormat{anspid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}
    
\DeclareFieldFormat{askid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}
    
\DeclareFieldFormat{ansid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangequestion}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{askid}%
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangeask}{%
  \bibstring{asked}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printaskdate%
  \iffieldundef{askedityear}%
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \bibstring{edited}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printaskeditdate}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \bibstring{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{askp}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{askpid}%
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangeans}{%
  \bibstring{answered}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printansdate%
  \iffieldundef{ansedityear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \bibstring{edited}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printanseditdate}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \bibstring{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{ansp}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{anspid}%
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangesite}{%
  \printfield{sitetopic}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{stackexchange}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangequestion}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeask}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeans}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangesite}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\cite{se:l3help}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To allow the use of `askdate` as labeldate, so the `authoryear` style (and other similar ones) does not print 'n.d.', we can use `\DeclareLabeldate` (§4.5.11 *Special Fields*, p. 238) as follows

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{askdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

There also is `\DeclareLabelname` (p. 238) with a similar syntax, if you want to see either `askp` or `ansp` as the author in `authoryear`/`authortitle` styles.

Comment: Very nice, and very complete answer (I knew I should refrain).  I would've had to steal the code too; but it probably would've taken me much longer to get everything in place.

Comment: This is an absolutely *fantastic* answer, so first and foremost I want to thank you.  That said, when using an `authoryear` style, the citation engine determines that there is no date: `... Project n.d.`.  Is there a way to map the `askdate` onto this field (which I'm presuming would be `date`)?

Comment: @SeanAllred Have a look at the edited answer. With `biblatex` we can explicitly choose which date fields are considered for the labeldate with `\DeclareLabeldate`.

Comment: Naive question: could this be packaged and put on CTAN? (There are some explicitly `tex.`s in there; on purpose?)

Comment: @Raphael There is precedence of a package on CTAN that just enables use of certain entry types: [`biblatex-bookinarticle`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-bookinarticle). Maïeul Rouquette has also brought [other packages to CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/author/rouquette) that only enable certain additional features and do not constitute a style in their own right. If you are talking about the `tex.`s in the URLs then they were on purpose, but that could probably be automated using the `sitetopic` field.

Comment: @PLK Am I right in thinking that one still has to define the dateparts separately? (See [Biblatex: Custom date fields](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288033/35864))

Comment: Currently yes, but I think I'll automate that too shortly.

Comment: @moewe Can you tell me if–apart from a minimized `.bbl` file–there is an advantage using `skipout`?

Comment: @Thorsten That is the standard way, `date` fields are defined in `biblatex`. I don't think it would do any harm not to `skipout` the `date` entries (I didn't actually check), but it won't do `biblatex` any good either since all the necessary information is already in the `.bbl`. Note that the date field handling will be made easier in the upcoming `biblatex` 3.4 (see PLK's comments above). Is there any specific reason you ask? Do you want to not `skipout` the date fields in the `.bbl`?

Comment: @Thorsten I suppose (I can't be certain) that that is done because the date is read from the datepart fields `year`, `month`, `day` from the `.bbl` and that it would only introduce redundancy to write an additional `date` to the `.bbl`. The `date` as written to the `.bib` is parsed by Biber and passed on to the `.bbl` in a form that is easy to digest.

Comment: Impressive but I guess it is not worth adapting and taking so much work for my use case. Sadly I think it is faster to just rename my custom field to @misc entries.

Comment: This is a great answer and just goes to show that vote count is no guide to quality: this deserves to have garnered far more votes in the years it has been here. May I ask if there is any advantage to using custom fields for things like dates and names? It's evident from existing entry types that different entries can share fields, so I'm wondering why `askdate` rather than `date`? Or `askp` rather than `author` (but maybe that's just because we have `askp` and `ansp`?)

Comment: @cfr I *think* I used `askdate`/`ansdate` and `askp`/`ansp` because the example in the question used them. But I also think that if you want question and answer in one entry it makes sense to avoid something as generic as `author` or `date`, because it's not entirely clear if the field refers to the question or the answer. You can definitely use existing fields and depending on the use case that may be more sensible than defining a new field with a new name. (For more usual bibliography entries I'd expect you can actually reuse a lot of fields and one define a couple of new ones.)