# bib entry for open source project

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I tried to use any of the available bib entries for adding open-source projects to my CV, but none of them are of my liking. Is there a way to add this functionality to bibtex? I would be interested in somehow a nice formatting of a project (instead of everything showing up on a single line), where I could add the project title, type of license, url, etc.

I use the [medium-length-professional-cv template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv). A bibtex record looks like the following:

```
@electronic{CPCPL:AESA_v1_0,
    Author = {Alejandro M. Arag{\'o}n},
    Date-Added = {2014-08-13 09:40:31 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-08-13 09:50:19 +0000},
    Howpublished = {Programming language: {\C++}; Code license: GNU Lesser GPL; Catalogue identifier: AESA\_v1\_0; Distribution format: tar.gz},
    Note = {Revisions:},
    Title = {cpp-array, from \textit{\uppercase{C}omput. \uppercase{P}hys. \uppercase{C}ommun.} \href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2014.01.005}{185(2014)1681}},
    Url = {http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/AESA_v1_0.html},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/AESA_v1_0.html}}
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm not happy with it:

[image]

Comment: Do you use `biblatex`, as the tag suggests?

Comment: Or `bibtex` as the other tag suggests?

Comment: I use bibtex, but I added biblatex not to limit the scope to the former.

Comment: Things like the license aren't normally considered 'bibliographic' data, so I'm struggling to see what sort of output you want. Perhaps you could add an example of the format you expect to see in the output?

Comment: @JosephWright I have added a picture of what I have so far, but as I said, I don't like it. As you can see, it follows a list of publications, and thus I thought I could use the same bibtex framework to include these projects.

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon I was hoping you'd have an idea of the sort of output you _do_ want: it's hard to give a good answer otherwise.

Comment: I do have an idea, as you can see in the image. I don't like it, but it's still an idea. As I put in the original post, it would be nice not to have all the information in a single line, but I have no idea how to accomplish something like that in a bibtex entry. Say you put put in a single line the title of the project, and then in a sort of borderless table, all the info of the project, like version, url, license type, etc.

Comment: Well, with [`biblatex` one could just add a new datatype (as described here)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864). What exactly are the possible bits of information you want displayed (licence, language, catalogue identifier, distribution format, revisions, ...)? A proper specification instead of just the picture would help greatly.

Comment: The fields would be, [for example](http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/AESA_v1_0.html): Code license, Authors, Program title, Catalogue identifier, Journal reference, Programming language, Computer platforms, Operating systems, RAM, Keywords, URL, Repository.

Comment: Then with `biblatex` you can proceed exactly as in the post I linked to above. You will have to define/declare the new fields and have to write code that can use the new fields. It would be best to do that within a new entry type `@software` or similar. Are you interested in an answer to your question that goes down a similar route as above?

Comment: I will work a bit on that suggestion and I'll post my solution for whoever wants it in the future. Thanks @moewe

Comment: @moewe have you tried the code in that link you pointed out? I get the `[se:l3help]` printed but no bibliographic entry is output. Do you have an idea where my problem may be?

Comment: Yes, I did run the code marked as MWE in the *answer* and got exactly the output in the picture below (that doesn't come as a surprise, seeing that I was the one to post the answer `;-)`). Your getting `[se:l3help]` can have several reasons: Did you run (pdf/yourfavourite)LaTeX and Biber on the file? At least `pdflatex mwe` `biber mwe` `pdflatex mwe` `pdflatex mwe`? Did you get any warning/error messages? (The reference to Biber is not that visible in the answer, but it is implied by the title and the MWE itself.)

Comment: I didn't notice the answer was yours :P
I did run it with pdflatex and biber but i just don't get the reference. I'm using TeXShop so I had to change to biber in the Engine section. But this doesn't work still.

Comment: Exactly. Biber output (with lots of those warnings of uninitialized values):`Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /var/folders/82/cmrzmtbn3v5_b4l2980xrhmc0000gn/T/par-61617261676f6e/cache-a3cdad92316c60c9c5179d80d6bb51a7a024393c/inc/lib/Biber/DataModel.pm line 63.

INFO - This is Biber 1.9

INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'

INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'

INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0

INFO - Processing section 0

INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0

INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8

INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'`

Comment: I deleted it, but biber creates the folder again and I get the same problem. Still the citation doesn't show up.

Comment: @moewe Of course I had tried that, I removed actually tree folders at the same level (T,C and O), Biber only recreates the first 2. By the way, `biber -v` gives you the version of biber, and I checked and there's no way to run a _verbose_ mode if that's what you wanted. I tried updating my `\TeX` distribution, but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this lengthy discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16456/discussion-between-moewe-and-aaragon), since it is not really to the point of the original post.