# Problems creating a new kind of bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm starting to approach the problem of automated typesetting of `git` change logs, using `biblatex` and `biber` as a helping hand, and I'm having great difficulty understanding both what I'm doing and how to build `biblatex` controls nicely.

Here's what I've got so far. I'm sorry the MWE isn't a bit smaller; I almost gave myself a hernia getting down to this:

mwe111.tex:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[%
    datamodel=gitlog,
    bibstyle=gitlog,
    sorting=none,
    date=iso8601,
    firstinits=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe111.gll}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Change Log},type=gitcommit]
\end{document}
```

mwe111.gll:

```
@gitcommit{9dce109,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-15},
 title = {Initial commit
},
 commithash = {9dce10970bb6be976ce59f76dd28e52abeb3b103} }
@gitcommit{f558cdd,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-15},
 title = {First code to build pseudo-bibfile
},
 commithash = {f558cddc5a95acb1c081ead6f6e81cb9941941a0} }
@gitcommit{240f4c9,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-15},
 title = {Added data model (not working) - now we step back a bit
},
 commithash = {240f4c9dbb22631f6098fbe45c409ef58cdddb09} }
@gitcommit{b4629f6,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-16},
 title = {First working version full of restrictions
},
 commithash = {b4629f6bb7504b2d6e4a677294a761e1d1d5c659} }
@gitcommit{d651d24,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-17},
 title = {Gradually improving things (especially understanding)
},
 commithash = {d651d249a3a14fd270a0f40e5d8124f6c552cc5b} }
@gitcommit{4c1dd2c,
 author = {Brent Longborough},
 date = {2015-11-17},
 title = {Making an MWE for TeX.SX
},
 commithash = {4c1dd2c540ff8a2f2976d972d15071c1f54f9379} }
```

gitlog.dbx:

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{gitcommit}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  title,
  commithash
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=name]{
  author
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date]{
  date
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[gitcommit]{
  title,
  author,
  date,
  commithash
}
```

gitlog.bbx:

```
\ProvidesFile{gitlog.bbx}
[\abx@bbxid]

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printfield{entrykey}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{%
    \hspace\labelsep\ttfamily##1}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\newbibmacro*{begentry}{}
\newbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{gitcommit}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newblock%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{commithash}
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro*{commithash}{%
    \printtext{%
       \printfield{commithash}%
}}

\endinput
```

Now, so far this sort of works (the typography is awful, but that's not the important problem at this stage), except that the "commithash" field is not printed:

[image: git changelog - typeset output]

Obviously I must have missed out something important, but have no idea what it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Related (but of course not specific to the problem here) [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864).

Comment: @moewe Yes, thanks, I had seen that, but had a great deal of difficulty understanding the answer (my fault, not yours! -- the example itself had complex requirements).

Comment: I added the link more for the "linked questions"/related feature than to solve the problem here. I didn't actually know that the csv list thingy was that sensitive when I wrote the answer. Plus a great deal there is about getting `date` fields right as well as localisation features. If you can put your finger on a specific point where the answer could be more understandable or precise I would appreciate a pointer.

Comment: @moewe : No, thank you, I appreciate that. My real problem was (will be) getting to grips with the different layers of bibliography entry formatting. I'm sure there'll be more questions later!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `biblatex`/Biber are a bit sensitive to space and punctuation in `\DeclareDatamodelFields`.
The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) warns in the explanation to `\DeclareDatamodelFields` (p. 160)

> As usual in TeX csv lists, make sure each element is immediately followed by a comma or the closing brace—no extraneous whitespace.

If I add a comma after the field names everything works just as expected.

You will find that there is no need to declare standard fields such as `date`, `title` and `author`, those are already there.

A working `gitlog.dbx` could be

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{gitcommit}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  commithash,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[gitcommit]{
  title,
  author,
  date,
  commithash,
}
```