# Is it possible to create biblatex datamodels entries programatically?

Tags: biblatex, languages

I'm trying to add some multi language support for a custom data model in `biblatex`.

I'm following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175896/7561). And have a functional prototype. However, when I started migrating the fields, it seems that it is quite repetitive to put different languages to each one of them, like

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{
  organization,%
  title,%
  country,%
  country-es,%
  country-en,%
  description,%
  description-es,%
  description-en%
}
```

I'm looking for a way to put a loop in there (somehow), such that I can automatically create the different versions of each field.

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{
  organization,%
  title,
  % some language to support the following
  foreach f in (country, description)
    foreach l in (, -es, -en)
      print f l,
}
```

I didn't find information on what language biblatex uses to process this `.dbx` files.

I know that I can use some external program to generate the `.dbx` file and then just use it. But I was looking for something that could be maintained and compiled automatically with the project in LaTeX.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since a `.dbx` is going to be (used as) an external file anyway most of the time, I would just go with automatic creation by your favourite script language. I don't think that the `DeclareDatamodelFields`-syntax allows for programming-like structures. I might be wrong here, but it could just be a list parser behind it.

Comment: Any news here? I feel this more a feature request for Biber, if you don't want to use a script language to create the `.dbx`. (Why don't you want to create the `.dbx` from a script?)

Comment: I was thinking to have something similar to what `biblatex` does natively. But I ended up doing it with an script outside, and used the generated files.

Comment: Mhh, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "what `biblatex` does natively". There is a big file `blx-dm.def` with all the known fields, there is no shortcut in there. BTW If you managed to solve your problem, you might want to post a self-answer so future readers with a similar problem can see your solution.

Comment: I was checking that file, but there is some `latex` code that produces some entries, maybe I didn't understand it well. But, my solution is not a solution, is a patch actually. As I did it by hand. In that case the answer will be 'no, there is no way of doing it automatically'.

Answer (score 2):

The `.dbx` files are simply processed like normal LaTeX, so in theory you can use every tool that LaTeX offers you. But `\DeclareDatamodelFields` and friends process their mandatory (second) argument with `\docsvlist{#2}`, which means that the input can not be arbitrary, but must be a comma-separated list of strings. So a loop *within* `\DeclareDatamodelFields` is ruled out, but there is no problem with building loops *outside* of `\DeclareDatamodelFields`.

In the MWE there are two nested loops. The outer loop (`\adn@dbx@fieldloop`) loops over the field names, the inner (`\adn@dbx@langloop`) over the language names. With `expl3` you might be able to obtain a more natural loop-like structure instead of the unusual structure imposed by `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{adn.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{adn.dbx}[2018/10/24 example for loops in dbx files]
\def\adn@dbx@langloop#1#2{%
  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{#1-#2}}

\def\adn@dbx@fieldloop#1{%
  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{#1}%
  \forcsvlist{\adn@dbx@langloop{#1}}{es,en}%
}

\forcsvlist{\adn@dbx@fieldloop}{country,description}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, datamodel=adn]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author         = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title          = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date           = {1980},
  description    = {Vanilla},
  description-es = {¡Hola!},
  description-en = {How do you do?},
  country        = {Plaincountry},
  country-es     = {Spain},
  country-en     = {England},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \printfield{description}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{description-es}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{description-en}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{country}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{country-es}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{country-en}%
  \newunit
  \finentry}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby, Humphrey (1980). On the Importance of the Civil Service. Vanilla. ¡Hola! How do you do? Plaincountry. Spain. England.]

Since `.dbx` files are usually files that remain constant over many projects and are probably only generated once, I still consider it not a bad idea to generate such a file with an external scripting language. You would save on the overhead induced by the loops on each LaTeX run.