# Patching endyear in custom datamodel for correct sorting

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-sourcemap

I'm creating a custom datamodel, similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175896/7561. But I can't make the dates sort when `endyear` is not properly defined into the `date`.

### My setup

I want to use a `date` field to hold a range of dates (I'm not sure if there is a better way) and sort the entries based on such range. However, I want to be be able to do the following:

- Leave open ranges (`1994/`) to default them to present, that is 1994-present
- Transform ranges of the same year into a single one (`1994/1994`) to 1994 instead of 1994-1994
- Use a short hand for same year ranges instead of writing `1994/1994`, use a simple 1994 in the date field

#### Sorting

For the sorting I adjust another example, the important part (I think) is this

```
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{endyear}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
```

So I put the sort by `endyear` before the `year`. Thus, the entries should be sorted by end year, then resorted by the starting year, right?

#### Data

If you test the example below, you will see that the entry `test3` is misplaced.

[image: bad test3]

I think that is because, despite the patch of the source map is not working. As the `endyear` will be empty and then it will default to the `9999` in the literal part of the sorting.

However, if one changes the entry to

```
  @test{test3,
    title           = {A. third},
    date            = {1994/1994},
  }
```

Then the order is respected.

[image: ok entry]

### The problem

So, I think the problem is this map

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=year]
      \step[fieldset=endyear, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

However, the `biblatex` documentation says that it should work.

#### Question

So, how can I fix the map or redesign the solution in order to patch the missing `endyears` and defult them to `year`. Notice that when a blank `endyear` is passed it should remain blank, so I can default it to "present".

### Full code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @test{test1,
    title           = {Second},
    date  = {1994/2000},
  }

  @test{test2,
    title           = {This should be first},
    date            = {1994/},
  }

  @test{test3,
    title           = {A. third},
    date            = {1994},
  } 

  @test{test4,
    title           = {B. fourth},
    date            = {1994/1994},

  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{title}

  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=datepart]{
    year,%
    endyear,%
    month,%
    endmonth%
  }

  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=date]{
    date%
  }

  \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[cvmisc]{%
    date,%
    title%
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[datamodel=test, backend=biber, sortcites, sorting=ymdtn]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSortingScheme{ymdtn}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{endyear}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{99}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{99}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \name{sortname}
    \name{author}
    \name{editor}
    \name{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

% Patch endyears that are not declared according to biblatex manual example
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=year]
      \step[fieldset=endyear, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

% The range date macro
\newbibmacro*{range-date}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
  {}
  {\printtext{%
      % If the item is in the same year, 
      \iffieldsequal{year}{endyear}%
      % compress
      {\mkbibdateshort{}{month}{}}%
      % else, print the date
      {\mkbibdateshort{year}{month}{}}%
      \iffieldundef{endyear}%
      {}%
      {% print the dash if a month range was given
        \ifthenelse{\( \iffieldsequal{year}{endyear} \and \iffieldundef{month} \)}{}{\bibdatedash}%
        % if a range is given but blank, 
        \iffieldequalstr{endyear}{}%
        % default to "present"
        {present}%
        % else, print a range
        {%
          \mkbibdateshort{endyear}{endmonth}{}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}


% Dummy driver for testing
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{test}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \printfield{title}%
    \newunit%
    \usebibmacro{range-date}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{document}

  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you point to a place where the `biblatex` docs say your map should work. The date fields are always a bit special and I think they are only parsed after the mapping step, so certain things might not work as expected.

Comment: I saw it from the page 159, v.3.4. It doesn't refer to dates specifically, but for a note field. I assumed that it should work in the same way for dates.

Comment: Mhh, OK as I say `date` fields are a bit special since they have to be parsed by `biblatex`. And the order of sourcemapping and parsing is exactly in such a way that this doesn't work smoothly. When you do the mapping, the `year` field isn't even present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the mapping

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{\A([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\Z}, replace=\regexp{$1/$1}]
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{\A([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2})\Z}, replace=\regexp{$1/$1}]
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{\A([0-9]{4})\Z}, replace=\regexp{$1/$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

dates such as `date = {1994}` are expanded to `date = {1994/1994}`.
Since `date = {1994/}` gives `endyear = {}` now everything should work just fine.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@test{test1,
  title = {Second},
  date  = {1994/2000},
}
@test{test2,
  title = {This should be first},
  date  = {1994/},
}
@test{test3,
  title = {A. third},
  date  = {1994},
} 
@test{test4,
  title = {B. fourth},
  date  = {1994/1994},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{title}
  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=date]{
    date%
  }
  \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[cvmisc]{%
    date,%
    title%
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[datamodel=test, backend=biber, sortcites, sorting=ymdtn]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSortingScheme{ymdtn}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{endyear}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{99}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{99}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \name{sortname}
    \name{author}
    \name{editor}
    \name{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{\A([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\Z}, replace=\regexp{$1/$1}]
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{\A([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2})\Z}, replace=\regexp{$1/$1}]
      \step[fieldsource=date, match=\regexp{\A([0-9]{4})\Z}, replace=\regexp{$1/$1}]
    }
  }
}

% The range date macro
\newbibmacro*{range-date}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
  {}
  {\printtext{%
      % If the item is in the same year, 
      \iffieldsequal{year}{endyear}%
      % compress
      {\mkbibdateshort{}{month}{}}%
      % else, print the date
      {\mkbibdateshort{year}{month}{}}%
      \iffieldundef{endyear}%
      {}%
      {% print the dash if a month range was given
        \ifthenelse{\( \iffieldsequal{year}{endyear} \and \iffieldundef{month} \)}{}{\bibdatedash}%
        % if a range is given but blank, 
        \iffieldequalstr{endyear}{}%
        % default to "present"
        {present}%
        % else, print a range
        {%
          \mkbibdateshort{endyear}{endmonth}{}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}


% Dummy driver for testing
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{test}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \printfield{title}%
    \newunit%
    \usebibmacro{range-date}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{document}

  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> [1] *This should be first.* 1994–present.
>
> [2] *Second.* 1994–2000.
>
> [3] *A. third.* 1994.
>
> [4] *B. fourth.* 1994.