# Biblatex-DW: Custom entry type for movies

Tags: biblatex-dw

I want to refer to some movies, wich I am using as examples, and list them also in my bibliograpy. So far I have added them to my bibliography file as @misc entries. Everything does what it is supposed to do, nevertheless i am not happy about how the movies appear. I either need to adapt the @misc entry type style (wich I dont use for anything else) or create a new style just for movies.

At the moment the whole stuff looks like that:

```
\documentclass[draft=true,fontsize=12,captions=nooneline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage}

%Biblatex
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,backend=biber,bibencoding=latin1,firstfull=true,ibidemfont=italic,maxbibnames=99,]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\bibliography{bibliographie.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et \addabbrvspace al\adddot}} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{urlseen = {zuletzt aufgerufen am}}

 \DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
 \DeclareFieldFormat{booktitleaddon}{{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
 \renewcommand{\titleaddonpunct}{\addcomma\space}

 \begin{document}

 ... Stuff here  .. 

 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

 \end{document}
```

In my .bib file I have e.g. an entry looking like that:

```
@Misc{potter4,
Title                    = {Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire},
Author                   = {Newell, Mike},
Year                     = {2005},
HowPublished             = {BluRay Disc}
}
```

As expected, this leads to a result looking like that:

> Newell, Mike: Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, BluRay Disc, 2005.

That output would make perfect sense, if it was a book, but as it is a movie (which strictly has no author) i want it actually to look more like:

> Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, directed by Mike Newell, BluRay Disc, 2005.

I have been trying out to create a new entry type "movie" by using \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes and \DeclareDatamodelFields but this was unsuccessful.

In addition to that, I also want to give a time code, e.g.: 1:19:25-1:19:30 , when citing the movie in text. Just adding these numbers to \footcite works of course, but I wonder if there is a way to define Pagination or Bookpagination so, that it automatically adds TC where it would normally output pp. (or S. in case of German language, as I am using it.)

Comment: Maybe you could use or get inspiration from [`biblatex-fiwi`](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-fiwi/doc/biblatex-fiwi.pdf)?

Comment: I found that style also, but if I use it, I will lose all the styles from -DW that work perfectly for my literature. Or can I use two styles at once?

Comment: No, you can't combine the styles. But you can steal some code from the latter to amend DW with a datamodel. Moewe wrote a nice answer describing how: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175896/29873

Comment: As the author of `biblatex-fiwi` I was wondering what specific requirements you have that my style does not meet (this is not a promise that I will include them, just curiosity).

Comment: @Simifilm: Actually I can't tell exactly. I am writing my dissertation and already finished 250 pages. The citations of the movies is one of the few points that are still missing. I don't remember why I chose the -DW style when I started the project, but I remember that plain, vanilla Biblatex did not produce the results I need. As the text is almost finished, I don't want to change the whole style I am using now.