# Creating an entry type identical to an already defined one

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Although there have been some posts on how to create new entry types in `biblatex` ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328138/biblatex-dw-custom-entry-type-for-movies), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501331/small-issues-with-new-entry-types-in-biblatex), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17276/creating-a-new-bibtex-entry-type), [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499424/extending-an-existing-biblatex-entry-type-or-creating-a-new-entry-type)), no post discusses how to create a new entry type that behaves exactly like one already defined.

For example, I would like to have a new entry types `@talk` that behaves like `@inproceedings`.

Why would I want this? Because I want two print two separate bibliographies in my CV. One including my talks:

```
\printbibliography[title=Talks, type=talk]
```

And another including my papers in proceedings:

```
\printbibliography[title=In Proceedings, type=inproceedings]
```

**OP edit:**
I'm more interested in a `biblatex` solution, rather than in a `bibtex` based one. I also excluded the `@event` type to avoid confusions.

Comment: I would select by keyword instead of entry type ...

Comment: your question appears to be specifically about biblatex, but you have tagged it bibtex and written bib(la)tex implying that you want answers for biblatex and bibtex (which would be quite different)

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, as I've just indicated in an edit, I'm more interested in the `biblatex` solution.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this problem is to define a filter for the bibliography using

```
\defbibfilter{talks}{%
  type=event or type=talk 
}
```

and then use

```
\printbibliography[title=Talks, filter=talks]
```