# How to verify if entry `country = {}` is empty in a custom BibLaTeX library?

Tags: biblatex, custom-bib

I have created a BibLaTeX library, which I use to organize all my oral and poster presentations. It is in fact a customized library with new data types and cite commands. I got all ideas from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175776/how-can-i-create-entirely-new-data-types-with-biblatex-biber) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/rSPhG2jd3Ks).

After some time of programming, I got the following code, which works quite well. I can use my own command `\printcontrib{BiB_entry}` in any text, but also I can do some listing at the end by, e.g., calling all Bib entries via the latter command.
Before I show the code, I would like to apologize already here that my code is probably some (evil?) hack. ;-)

**MWE**

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}


% The BibTeX library
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Contribution{Oral_2016_1,
  Type      = {Oral},
  Invited   = {True},
  Author    = {{\textbf{Author, One} and Author, Two and Author, Three}},
  Presenter = {{Author, One}},
  Title     = {{Some cool stuff about the Nanoworld}},
  Event     = {{Conference about XYZ}},
  Eventtype = {Conference},
  Place     = {},
  City      = {Helsinki (Finland) - Stockholm (Sweden)},
  Country   = {},
  Date      = {May 1$^{\rm st}$ - June 2$^{\rm nd}$},
  Period    = {},
  Year      = {2016},
  Note      = {}
}

@Contribution{Oral_2015_1,
  Type      = {Oral},
  Invited   = {Ture},
  Author    = {{\textbf{Author, One}}},
  Presenter = {{Author, One}},
  Title     = {{Exciting research on cool Nanostuff}},
  Event     = {{6$^{\rm th}$ Nanotechnology workshop}},
  Eventtype = {Workshop},
  Place     = {},
  City      = {Giessen},
  Country   = {Germany},
  Date      = {September 24$^{\rm th}$},
  Period    = {},
  Year      = {2015},
  Note      = {}
}

@Contribution{Oral_2015_2,
  Type      = {Oral},
  Invited   = {False},
  Author    = {{Author, One and Author, Two and \textbf{Author, Three}}},
  Presenter = {{Author, Three}},
  Title     = {{Nanochemistry at its edge}},
  Event     = {{18$^{\rm th}$ Summer School of Nanochemistry}},
  Eventtype = {School},
  Place     = {},
  City      = {Cassis},
  Country   = {France},
  Date      = {September 9$^{\rm th}$},
  Period    = {},
  Year      = {2015},
  Note      = {}
}
\end{filecontents*}

% The declaration of the entries.
\begin{filecontents}{contribution.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{contribution}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  type,
  invited,
  title,
  event,
  eventtype,
  place,
  city,
  country,
  date,
  period,
  year,
  note
}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  author,
  presenter
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[contribution]{
  type,
  invited,
  author,
  presenter,
  title,
  event,
  eventtype,
  place,
  city,
  country,
  date,
  period,
  year,
  note}
\end{filecontents}



% The standard LaTeX head, with a link to the chem-acs style and biber. The
% datamodel 'contribution' is also declared.
\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[datamodel=contribution,
            style=chem-acs,
            natbib=true,
            backend=biber]
           {biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



% Declare cite commands, the most important ones. Others will be added.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeevent}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext{\printfield{event}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citedate}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext{\printfield{date}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext{\printfield{year}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citecity}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext{\printfield{city}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citecountry}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext{\printfield{country}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printtext{\printfield{title}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthor}
    {\defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
     \defcounter{minnames}{99}%
     \defcounter{uniquename}{2}%
     \boolfalse{citetracker}%
     \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
     \usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\ifciteindex{\indexnames{labelname}}{}\printnames{labelname}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}




% My own command, which puts into format and prints the contribution.
\newcommand{\printcontrib}[1]{
    \citeauthor*{#1}, 
    \citetitle*{#1}, 
    \citeevent{#1},
    \citecity{#1} 
%
%   This works, but there is no 'if' that might find an empty 'country' field.
%   I would like to have:
%   If  : Country   = {} => Do not print '(\citecountry{#1})' 
%   Else: print (\citecountry{#1})
    (\citecountry{#1}),
%
%
%   Here is my first test amongst many others:
%   It works but there is a error: "! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)." 
%
%   \newlength{\strlen}\settowidth{\strlen}{\citecountry{#1}}
%   \ifdim\strlen=0\else(\citecountry{#1})\fi,
%   \let\strlen\relax 
%    
    \citedate{#1} (\citeyear{#1})
} 




\begin{document}

\chapter{Oral contributions}

\printcontrib{Oral_2016_1}\\\\
%
\noindent\printcontrib{Oral_2015_2}\\\\
%
\noindent\printcontrib{Oral_2015_1}\\\\
%

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: The output of the code from above]

So far so good. Now, there might be some entries in one BibLaTeX entry (see, e.g., Oral_2016_1 => Country = {}), that have no text inside the two {} because some info is missing (note that I would like to keep these brackets due to a couple of reasons ... .)

I would like to have a 'if ... do ... else do ...' part in the code, which checks if an entry is 'empty', so here `Country = {}`. Otherwise, as it is the case here, the are two brackets displayed in the text ().

I would like to have this if conditioning in particular in this command:

```
% My own command, which puts into format and prints the contribution.
\newcommand{\printcontrib}[1]{
    \citeauthor*{#1}, 
    \citetitle*{#1}, 
    \citeevent{#1},
    \citecity{#1} 
%
%   This works, but there is no 'if' that might find an empty 'country' field.
%   I would like to have:
%   If  : Country   = {} => Do not print '(\citecountry{#1})' 
%   Else: print (\citecountry{#1})
    (\citecountry{#1}),
%
%
%   Here is my first test amongst many others:
%   It works but there is a error: "! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)." 
%
%   \newlength{\strlen}\settowidth{\strlen}{\citecountry{#1}}
%   \ifdim\strlen=0\else(\citecountry{#1})\fi,
%   \let\strlen\relax 
%    
    \citedate{#1} (\citeyear{#1})
}
```

The `(\citecountry{#1})` command (note the `(` and `)` brackets) shall be only executed, if the entry `country` has some text, in other words, is not `Country = {}` in the BibLaTeX file.

I tried out a dozen of things. For instance, I tried several if conditions with help of the `ifmtarg`, `xstring` and `ifthen` packages but without any success. The only `half-solution` in the % quotation (below the text `% Here is my first test` in the MWE) somewhat works, however, with errors (you have to uncomment this such that it is compiled by LaTeX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `biblatex`, field formatting such as brackets or emphasis or italics should not be written into the macro directly in most cases, they should be achieved with `\DeclareFieldFormat`. That way you make sure that `biblatex` can properly detect empty fields and do nothing in that case.

You could just do

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{country}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citecountry}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{country}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

The field is then wrapped in brackets whenever it is shown and ignored otherwise. Note that there is no need to wrap a single `\printfield` into a `\printtext` without argument, `\printfield{country}` will do the same as `\printtext{\printfield{country}}`.

Instead of defining `\citecontrib` as you do now, you should probably just define a bibliography driver for `@contribution` like so (this is just a first rough shot at this, but you get the idea)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{country}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[contribution]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{event+venue+city+country+date}{%
  \printfield{eventtitle}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{eventtitleaddon}%
  \newunit
  \printeventdate
  \newunit
  \printfield{city}
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{country}
  \newunit}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{contribution}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+city+country+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}\printdate%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Then you can just use `\fullcite` and you are done.

Comment: For moewe: Question: If I work with '\newbibmacro' and '\DeclareBibliographyDriver' I automatically agree to all styles that are described in, e.g., '\usepackage[...]{biblatex}', '\documentclass' ... . E.g., the type of style for author and title can be changed by using '\usepackage[style=chem-acs]{biblatex}'. Furthermore date can be changed from '\documentclass[american]{book}' to '\documentclass[english]{book}'.
So, If I want this I would do it. However, if I want to keep a specific style I rather make use of '\DeclareFieldFormat' and '\DeclareCiteCommand'. Is that right?

Comment: @Krumpel I'm not entirely sure if I follow you, but I don't think you can say that in all generality. `\newbibmacro`, `\DeclareBibliographyDriver`, `\DeclareFieldFormat` and `\DeclareCiteCommand` do different things and work at different code levels. Which is prerenal depends on what exactly you want to achieve. It is true that `\newbibmacro` and `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` use the formats declared by `\DeclareFieldFormat`, expect if you explicitly disable that.

Comment: \@ moewe: Sorry for having confused you. It has taken a rather long time for me to understand, how things work in BibLaTeX. On that day, I was quite confused. Things are clear now, thx for your help. Later, I will show my solution ... .

Answer (score 4):

You should check whether the field exists as part of the `\DeclareCiteCommand` using `\iffieldundef` (or something similar; see section **4.6.2 Stand-alone Tests** in the [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)):

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citecountry}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\iffieldundef{country}{}{(\printtext{\printfield{country}})}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

and here is `\printcontrib`:

```
\newcommand{\printcontrib}[1]{%
  \citeauthor*{#1}, 
  \citetitle*{#1}, 
  \citeevent{#1},
  \citecity{#1} 
  \citecountry{#1},
  \citedate{#1} (\citeyear{#1})
}
```

You may also write a larger `\DeclareCiteCommand` rather using `\printcontrib`.

[image]

Comment: Perfect (+100 points) and thanks a lot! - In fact, I also tried this directly in the '\DeclareCiteCommand' environment with '\iffieldundef' but I got somewhat lost. And yes, I will consider 'You may also write a larger \DeclareCiteCommand rather using \printcontrib.', I will report on this - Question: in my code, how can I change '\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthor}' such that LaTeX uses the style specified in '\usepackage[..., style=chem-acs,', ...]'?

Comment: @Krumpel: Ask a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).

Comment: Okay, I didn't know. - Thanks a lot for your very quick help that has lead to a rolling stone: I'm currently exploring the vast possibilities of CV data automation in research via TeX/LaTeX/BibLaTeX/Python and without using MSWord etc.! When I have a suitable hack, I will present it here ... .

Comment: Please note that writing cite commands as `\printcontrib` with `\newcommand` by sticking several `\cite...` together is really bad style in `biblatex`. A command like this will not be able at all to handle pre or postnotes and multiple citations properly without much extra work, one should always use `\DeclareCiteCommand`.