# How to test if \printdate like commands do not print 'empty' text?

Tags: biblatex

This is a follow-up question to [How to verify if entry `country = {}` is empty in a custom BibLaTeX library?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349801/how-to-verify-if-entry-country-is-empty-in-a-custom-biblatex-library)

I have a custom BibLaTeX library with the BiBLaTeX entry `Contribution`, which I use to manage all my oral and poster contributions on conferences, workshops etc. Thanks to the help I got on the site mentioned above, I have a nice working system.

However, there are some cosmetic issues: I have an entry called `period` which includes the time period of, e.g., a conference. It shall appear behind the event title in brackets (see example below). In a `.dbx` file, I declare the entry field `period` as a date datatype, and I can therefore call the command `\printperiod`. So far, so good.

In some BibLaTeX entries, this field `period` is empty, so `period = {}`.

How can I find out via an 'if', 'then' 'else' condition, if `\printperiod` is printing text, so as to say if `period = {}`?

I tried out `\iffieldundef{period}`, `\ifciteindex` and other things but I don't get it working.

So far, here is first the MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{contribution.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{contribution}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  type,
  invited,
  title,
  event,
  eventshort,
  eventtype,
  league,
  url,
  place,
  city,
  country,
  year,
  note,
  timestamp
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=datepart]{
  year,
  month,
  day,
  periodyear,
  periodmonth,
  periodday
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  date,
  period,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  author,
  presenter,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[contribution]{
  type,
  invited,
  author,
  presenter,
  title,
  event,
  eventshort,
  eventtype,
  league,
  url,
  place,
  city,
  country,
  date,
  period,
  year,
  note,
  timestamp}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Contribution{Oral_2016_1,
  Type      = {Oral},
  Invited   = {invited},
  Author    = {Author1, A. and Author2, B. and Author3, C. and Author4, D.},
  Presenter = {Author2, B.},
  Title     = {{Cool stuff about the nano-world}},
  Event     = {{22$^{\rm nd}$ International Conference on Nanotechnology}},
  Eventshort= {{NANO-7}},
  Eventtype = {Conference},
  League    = {International},
  URL       = {},
  Place     = {Alto University},
  City      = {Helsinki},
  Country   = {Finland},
  Date      = {2016-05-31},
  Period    = {2016-05-22/2016-06-02},
  Year      = {2016},
  Note      = {},
  Timestamp = {}
}
@Contribution{Oral_2016_2,
  Type      = {Oral},
  Invited   = {},
  Author    = {Author1, A. and Author2, B. and Author3, C. and Author4, D.},
  Presenter = {Author1, B.},
  Title     = {{Cool stuff about the nano-world}},
  Event     = {{22$^{\rm nd}$ International Workshop on NanoPhenomena}},
  Eventshort= {{IWNP-8}},
  Eventtype = {Workshop},
  League    = {International},
  URL       = {},
  Place     = {University of Nano},
  City      = {Tokyo},
  Country   = {Japan},
  Date      = {2016-03-04},
  Period    = {},
  Year      = {2016},
  Note      = {},
  Timestamp = {}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[datamodel=contribution,
            style=chem-acs,
            dateabbrev=false,
            natbib=true,
            backend=biber]
           {biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



% My own command, which puts into format and prints the complete contribution.
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeallstuff}
  {\defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
   \defcounter{minnames}{99}%
   \defcounter{uniquename}{2}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {%
   \ifciteindex{\indexnames*{labelname}}{}\printnames{labelname}, %
   \iffieldundef{title}{}{\textit{\printtext{\printfield{title}}}\space}%
   \iffieldundef{event}{}{\printtext{\printfield{event}}}%
   \space(\printperiod)\addcomma\space% <============ What must I do there? 
   \iffieldundef{city}{}{\printtext{\printfield{city}}}%
   \iffieldundef{country}{\addcomma\space}{ \printtext{(\printfield{country}})\addcomma\space}%
   \printdate% <============ The same here? 
   \iffieldundef{note}{}{\addcomma\space\printtext{\printfield{note}}}%
   \iffieldundef{invited}{}{\addcomma\space{\textbf{\printtext{\printfield{invited}}}}}
   }   
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}




\begin{document}

\noindent\citeallstuff{Oral_2016_1}\\\\\\
\citeallstuff{Oral_2016_2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the MWE]

As one can see, the second citation has a () behind the event title, because the field 'period' is empty, `period = {}`. In this case, the two brackets should not appear but instead a comma and space.

Thanks for some help.

PS: Small additional question: How can I change, e.g., `May 31` to `May 31$^{\rm st}$`?

Comment: Your datamodel doesn't work for me in `bibilatex` 3.7/Biber 2.7. `date`-like fields must end in `date`, so you can' have `period`, it must be called `perioddate`.

Comment: Note that there is already the field `eventdate` for conference proceedings that you could probably reuse. There is also the field `venue` which you could use instead of maybe `place`.

Comment: Note that most of your `\iffieldindef`s are not necessary if you use `\DeclareFieldFormat` and `\newunit`/`\setunit` properly. Have a look at my alternative answer to your other question, maybe that can give you an idea of how to approach this in a more `biblatex`-y way. Read §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot, moewe! It is a good idea to use 'eventdate' and 'venue', I've completely overseen. Then, I will do what you propose below, and I will also consider this '\newunit' and '\setunit' stuff. I will let you know, probably this evening. - BTW: I use biber version 2.5 on Ubuntu 14.04, upgraded by a PPA (ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2016)

Comment: Ah, Biber 2.5 is a bit outdated now with 2.7 being out. On older Linux systems it can be a good idea to install vanilla TeX live (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864). But note that some of the code you have in your MWE will probably have to be adapted as mentioned in my comment above (if you decide to use `eventdate` though, you might be able to get away with few changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a combination of two issues here.

No. 1 is that you should not write bare formatting into bibmacros or cite commands, you should use `\DeclareFieldFormat` and friends.

So write

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{perioddate}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
```

and then later

```
\printperioddate
```

and the period date will be wrapped in parentheses. With this method you do not have to check if the field is empty. If it is empty you get nothing, if it contains something you get that back in the correct format.
If you really must check if a date is defined, the standard method is to check for its year part

```
\iffieldundef{periodyear}
  {<no date>}
  {<date>}
```

`biblatex` will only ever print a date if it has a year and if the date has a year, `biblatex` prints at least that.

All of this does not work with `biblatex` 3.7/Biber 2.8 however, if you input empty fields 'explicitly' as

```
perioddate = {}
```

In that case you will get back `periodyear = {}` which confuses everybody, because as far as `biblatex` concerns that counts as a defined year.

This is a known bug that will be resolved with Biber 2.8, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/528.

In the meantime all you can do is drop the strange habit of writing `perioddate = {}` for empty fields instead of leaving them out of the entry altogether. If you for some reason don't want to do that, let Biber do it for you with

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=perioddate, match=\regexp{^$}, final]
      \step[fieldset=perioddate, null]
      }
    }
}
```