# Setting a new entrytype

Tags: biblatex, bibentry

Doing as it has been suggested on this site, and also having looked in the manual for `biblatex.pdf`, I cannot figure out the difference between `DeclareDatamodeFields` and `DeclareDatamodeEntryfields`. I only get the address field as the result (Paris in this case). `pdflatex`, `biber`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[datamodel=manuscript,bibstyle=verbose,citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{manuscript.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{manuscript}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{datation,title,library}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[manuscript]{
title,
library,
datation}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{maniscript.bib}
@manuscript{P1470,
    library={BNF},
    address={Paris},
    datation={\textsc{viii}\textsuperscript{e} s.}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{manuscript.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually pretty close. If you look at [moewe's canonical answer on the topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175896/105447) you can get a better grasp on the possibilities and requirements of creating a new entrytype.

Still, to get your new fields typeset in the bibliography, you are critically missing a driver for you `manuscript` entrytype. I'm not sure the format you are looking for, but this serves as an example:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{manuscript}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{library}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{datation}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

I've also removed title and library from your `.dbx` file, as they are already defined by default. You should still add them to your `\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[manuscript]{...` as you do. Also, note that setting both `citestyle` and `bibstyle` to `verbose` is equivalent to the more direct `style=verbose`.

In full:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[datamodel=manuscript,style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{manuscript.dbx}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{manuscript}
  \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{datation}
  \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[manuscript]{
    title,
    library,
    location,
    datation}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{manuscript.bib}
@manuscript{P1470,
  library = {BNF},
  title = {A title},
  location = {Paris},
  datation = {\textsc{viii}\textsuperscript{e} s.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{manuscript}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{library}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{datation}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[manuscript]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\addbibresource{manuscript.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can, and should, examine closer moewe's linked answer, particularly the formatting directives. Also, you can redefine your bibdriver to the order of fields and punctuation of your liking.

Comment: Thank you very much! You explained by a very clear and hands-on code what I have long tried to master.

Comment: Thank you for laying all out in such a complete reply. The need for such consultation emerges for people like me because I have only been trained in programming languages like Fortran77, Algol, and a bit of Pascal, and every step (1. Data model 2.driver 3. field format requires a conceptual "retooling". :) Making a driver can still be grasped, but "DeclareFieldFormat", frankly, was beyond my conceptual reach even though I read the manual. :)

Comment: @DmitryStarostin Indeed, `biblatex`'s jargon needs some getting used to, but once you grasp it you'll see it has a logic. I hope it has been enough to get you started. moewe's answer, specially, is very thorough. But old time languages should be no impediment. I started myself with Basic on a TK85 (a ZX81 clone) with K7 tape memory and all!  :)

Comment: Thank you! It does have logic indeed, one just has to get accustomed to the relatively "slow" flow of definitions, which are nevertheless all conceptually justified. I have been using Latex for about ten years now, and it has been teaching me a very high-level philosophy of programming. It is not only Turing-complete, it does have a very precise conceptual definition of every step that has taught me since to at least understand such languages as Python and Java.