# Creating a Custom .bib File

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, custom-bib

I am trying to create a custom source.bib file. Default templates are not helping me since my company has a different fields ordering in .bib file.

Assume I am working under the @mis type.

```
@misc{A14-002,
  author       = {},
  title        = {TM/TC Database Design Architecture},
  howpublished = {},
  year         = {},
  keywords     = {RD}
}
```

Rather that above example I want to create a custom-bib file as shown below:

```
@template{A14-002,
  document_code = {},
  title         = {},
  keywords      = {}
}
```

Is there a easy way to accomplish that. I am very newbie at working on biblatex files. But any solution will be welcomed (I am trying to avoid complex macros). Thank you in advance!

Comment: The entry you show is completely non-standard, so you need to define a new driver along with relevant bibmacros. This can be done, but is some work. A guide for creating your own entry types can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864

Comment: @moewe thank you! I will check that solution!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like [this](http://gabrielelanaro.github.io/blog/2014/12/01/latex-bibliography-in-5-minutes.html)?
With that you should be able to create a custom bibliography style.

Comment: Thank you! I will check that. Then I will share my results with you!

Comment: Note that BibTeX styles generated by `makebst` only support the common BibTeX entry types. If you want support for a custom type like `@template` in the question, you need to add that manually afterwards.