# misc-like Biblatex entry type with article-like styling for title

Tags: biblatex

Most of my citations to news articles. Many are from newspapers and magazines, for which the `@article` entry type seems appropriate. However, many are also from wire services (like AP, AFP, and Reuters), for which I have been using `@misc`.  With this coding scheme, the title of the wire report ends up with same styling as the journal's title, which doesn't make sense to me.

Ideally, I would like to assign to at least the non-print news articles* a custom entry type `@news`  that works like `@misc` except with article-like styling for the title (i.e. Roman typeface inside quotation marks in the default) while leaving the `@misc` available for true miscellany. However, I'm wary of defining a new entry type if it requires defining the output style myself, since this is just a manuscript and not the finished book. I haven't really decided which citation system to use and don't want to right now. I just want the news citations to have a consistent look.

Any simple solution would be appreciated. This [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175896/40803) by moewe seems an overkill, but I'm not against some new definitions so long as they are simple. Thank you.

* I haven't decided whether I should assign this entry type instead of `@article` to print news articles as well for perfect consistency. Suggestions are welcome.

Minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{news.bib}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{filecontents}{news.bib}

@article{NYT:Pelletiere:A_War_Crime,
    author   = {Pelletiere, Stephen C.},
    title    = {A War Crime Or an Act of War?},
    journal  = {New York Times},
    pages    = {A29},
    date     = {2003-01-31},
}

@misc{AP:Hunt:Bush_Says_Saddam,
    author   = {Terence Hunt},
    title    = {Bush Says Saddam Would `Get His Ass Kicked' in Gulf War},
    organization = {Associated Press},
    date     = {1990-12-20},
}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

Foo\autocites{NYT:Pelletiere:A_War_Crime}{AP:Hunt:Bush_Says_Saddam}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a new entry type, the standard way to do that is to define a new entry type as shown in [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864). A new entry type needs to be defined in the data model and needs a bibliography driver (the driver could be aliased), so some additional code would be needed.

A cheaper alternative is to set up a new entry type for the `.bib` files that is then remapped by the backend (Biber) to a known entry type with some additional property. Since you want `@news` to behave like `@misc` except for the title formatting, we can remap `@news` to `@misc`+`entrysubtype = {news},`. In the `title` format we then check for `entrysubtype = {news},`. This is the same approach `biblatex` takes with `@phdthesis`, which is remapped to `@thesis`+`type = {phdthesis},`.

Note that with this kind of setup you can only tell a `@news` from a `@misc` by its `entrysubtype` field. In particular you cannot filter `\printbibliography` for `@news` directly, you need to filter for `@misc`+`entrysubtype = {news},`. This may of may not have implications if you want to filter for `@news` and `@misc` at the same time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[typesource=news,       typetarget=misc]
      \step[fieldset=entrysubtype, fieldvalue=news]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{news}
    {\mkbibquote{#1}}
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{NYT:Pelletiere:A_War_Crime,
  author   = {Pelletiere, Stephen C.},
  title    = {A War Crime Or an Act of War?},
  journal  = {New York Times},
  pages    = {A29},
  date     = {2003-01-31},
}
@news{AP:Hunt:Bush_Says_Saddam,
  author       = {Terence Hunt},
  title        = {Bush Says Saddam Would \mkbibquote{Get His Ass Kicked} in Gulf War},
  organization = {Associated Press},
  date         = {1990-12-20},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo\autocites{NYT:Pelletiere:A_War_Crime}{AP:Hunt:Bush_Says_Saddam}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Stephen C. Pelletiere. “A War Crime Or an Act of War?” In: New York Times (Jan. 31, 2003), A29; Terence Hunt. “Bush Says Saddam Would ‘Get His Ass Kicked’ in Gulf War”. Associated Press, Dec. 20, 1990.]

Comment: Quite elegant! Does this mean that if I simply put `entrysubtype = {news}` in applicable `@misc` entries, I can save the `DeclareSourcemap`? I don't mind doing that. In fact, it may be preferable. (What do you think?)

Comment: @bongbang Yes (but I'm guessing you have tried and found that yourself by now). I have no strong opinion on what I think is the better solution. It's completely up to your needs and your taste. If you go for `@news` and the sourcemap, it is easier to extend it to a bona fide new entry type should you want to in the future. But if that is of little concern, you might as well use `entrysubtype = {news}` directly.

Comment: Is there a way to apply the `entrysubtype` condition to `@online` as well without doubling the code? Or perhaps I should stick with `@misc` and add the `url` field as needed? Also, I notice that you replaced the hard quotation marks inn the second title. It's an issue that bedevils me---whether original punctuation (e.g. double vs single vs guillemet) should be the title or the block quote.  I can't find a good style-guide authority on that. If you can tell me the reason in the Latex of Biblatex context, I'll just go with that.

Comment: @bongbang Assuming you manually put the `entrysubtype` into your entries, you can just change the `\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]` above to `\DeclareFieldFormat[misc,online]` and things should work the same for both `@misc` and `@online`. There is little difference between `@online` and `@misc` for most uses. The most interesting difference is that `@online` will show the URL even if the URL is disabled with the global option `url=false,`.

Comment: @bongbang I don't have very string feelings about the quotation marks. Using `\mkbibquote` ensures that they nest properly with any outer quotation marks that might be added by `biblatex`. Of course the quotation marks may come out different from the source material. (I almost always replace manual quotation marks with `csquotes` commands because I don't want to have to think about whether or not the marks are typeset correctly.)