# Customizing biblatex citation with entry type for ICD-206 standards

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago, footcite

### Background

I am writing a Turabian-styled thesis and use the [biblatex-chicago](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago?lang=en) package for my citations and bibliography generation. Citations are all footnotes, but *unclassified sources* are cited in Chicago style and *classified sources* have to follow [ICD 206](https://www.dni.gov/files/documents/ICD/ICD%20206.pdf) D.3.a.(6).(a)-(i) for Source Reference Citation (SRC). This means there are extra fields and the order is different between unclassified and classified citations.

*Source Reference Citation (SRC) Order:*

> 1. Portion Marking that presents the classification of the SRC; I.E. (U) or (S)
> 2. Identification of the information originator (author, producer, owner, publishing office)
> 3. Unambiguous source identifier or document number
> 4. Portion marked classification of the document title
> 5. Document title, with volume and issue number, if applicable
> 6. Date of publication or access
> 7. Page number, if applicable
> 8. Classification of the information extracted from the source
> 9. Overall classification of the source document
> 10. Source descriptor portion marking, if applicable
> 11. Source descriptor statement, if applicable

### How I Think It Works

I can think of three ways to accomplish this.

1. Use one of the other `@categories` and put the information in the wrong sections just to get the order correct in the citation.
2. Use a keyword in the `.bib` entry that cues biblatex to order entry differently.
3. Create a new entry type called `@src` that has the categories I need and orders them properly.

Option 1 would just be using `@misc` and the `notes` field to input my own long string.

`refs.bib`

```
@misc{sourceReference1,
  author = {{(U) Smith, John}},
  notes  = {{12345678; (U) The Title...; 17 March 2022; Unclassified; Super Secret}},
}

@article{chicagoReference1,
  title       = {Has the ODNI Improved US Intelligence Analysis?},
  author      = {Gentry, John A},
  year        = {2015},
  publisher   = {Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

This would come close, producing something like:

> 1. (U) Smith, John. 12345678; (U) The Title...; 17 March 2022;
>    Unclassified; Super Secret
> 2. John A. Gentry, "Has the ODNI Improved US Intelligence Analysis?"
>    (Taylor & Francis, 2015)

Ideally, option 3 would be cleanest if it is possible. For example:

`refs.bib:`

```
@src{sourceReference1,
  src_class   = {U},              % Classification of the entire SRC
  originator  = {Smith, John},    % Originator, author, producer, owner, etc
  identifier  = {12345678},       % Unambiguous source identifier
  title_class = {U},              % Classification of the title
  title       = {The Title...},   % Title of the document
  date        = {2022-03-17},     % Date of publication
  page        = {},               % Page number, if applicable
  info_class  = {Unclassified},   % Classification of the information extracted
  doc_class   = {Super Secret},   % Classification of the source document
  descriptor  = {},               % Source descriptor, if applicable
  keywords    = {classified}      % To separate out in the bibliography
}

@article{chicagoReference1,
  title       = {Has the ODNI Improved US Intelligence Analysis?},
  author      = {Gentry, John A},
  year        = {2015},
  publisher   = {Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

`master.tex:`

```
\documentclass{turabian-researchpaper}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pass,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
    \addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a test.
\footcite{SourceReference1}.    %This won't work because a @SRC is made up right now
This is also a test. 
\footcite{chicagoReference1}

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This should produce two footnotes:

> 1. (U) Smith, John; 12345678; (U) The Title...; 17 March 2022;
>    Unclassified; Super Secret
> 2. John A. Gentry, "Has the ODNI Improved US Intelligence Analysis?"
>    (Taylor & Francis, 2015)

The first footnote would be in a different order than the other one, because the other one is the standard biblatex-chicago style. To make things easier, I put the "@src" information in order in the .bib file. In the actual bibliography I would separate them using keywords, I know how to do that separately.

Any ideas of how or if possible to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864 explains how you can create a new type in `biblatex`. Problem is that it is going to be a bit more tricky to integrate this into `biblatex-chicago` than it is to integrate a new type into a standard style.

Comment: @moewe thanks for that it is a good starting point, I tested it independently and it works great but you're right, the moment I try and integrate it into `{biblatex-chicago}` the compile fails due to `No driver for 'stackexchange' found`. It works in `[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}`, but recreating all the style modifications from `{biblatex-chicago}` would be a lot of work. I just need to find a way to add the `@stackexchange` from the example to `biblatex-chicago` and I should be good.

Comment: For `biblatex-chicago` it is not enough to define a driver for the new type with `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{<new type>}`, you also need to define a new driver for full citations called `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:<new type>}`. (You will likely have to do *a lot* more, but at least for me adding the driver made the error go away.)

Comment: @moewe Adding `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:stackexchange}` removed the error, and added the citation to my Bibliography without error, but the footnote citation is blank. Progress!

Comment: Mhhh, in https://gist.github.com/moewew/ab9121242f08eac3892a81223f2af7b2 I get a working footnote.

Comment: @moewe Aha! I forgot copy the rest of the info below `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{stacke xchange}` to below `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:stackexchange}` This seems to meet my need then! Thank you! If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: If the definition is going to be the same `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{cite:stackexchange}{stackexchange}` might be cheaper than having to copy the entire driver definition, but I believe there are subtle differences between citations and references in Chicago style, so you may have to have two independent declarations.

Comment: Fortunately, anything classified gets cited as ICD-206 style which ignores Chicago/Turabian style. So I can just create a `@classified` data type (like stackexchange in this example) with all the fields I need using this example and it should work as a catch-all for any classified source I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) has a guide to defining new entry types in `biblatex`.

In principle that guide can be used for all `biblatex` styles, but *integrating* the new type into the style so that everything works seamlessly can be a bit of a challenge especially with a complex style such as `biblatex-chicago`.

The following code seems to work OK-ish with `biblatex-chicago`.

The main obstacle to using the code from [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/35864) directly was that `biblatex-chicago` needs specific drivers for citations as well, so that each `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{<new type>}` needs a corresponding `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:<new type>}` for citations.

```
\begin{filecontents}{stackexchange.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{stackexchange}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  sitekey,
  sitetopic,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  askp,
  ansp,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=date, skipout]{
  askdate,
  ansdate,
  askeditdate,
  anseditdate}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=verbatim]{
  askid,
  askpid,
  anspid,
  ansid,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[stackexchange]{
  sitekey,
  sitetopic,
  askid,
  askp,
  askpid,
  ansp,
  anspid,
  ansid,
  askyear,
  askmonth,
  askday,
  ansyear,
  ansmonth,
  ansday,
  askedityear,
  askeditmonth,
  askeditday,
  ansedityear,
  anseditmonth,
  anseditday,
  title}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[datamodel=stackexchange,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{filecontents*}{english-stack.lbx}
  \ProvidesFile{english-stack.lbx}[2014/05/07 english with additions for stackexchange]
  \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
  \NewBibliographyString{asked,answered,edited}
  \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
    inherit   = {english},
    asked     = {{asked}{asked}},
    answered  = {{answered}{answered}},
    edited    = {{edited}{edited}},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-stack}

\DeclareFieldFormat[stackexchange]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{askpid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{anspid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{askid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{ansid}{%
  \mkbibparens{\ifhyperref
    {\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangequestion}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{askid}%
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangeask}{%
  \bibstring{asked}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printaskdate%
  \iffieldundef{askedityear}%
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \bibstring{edited}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printaskeditdate}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \bibstring{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{askp}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{askpid}%
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangeans}{%
  \bibstring{answered}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printansdate%
  \iffieldundef{ansedityear}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \bibstring{edited}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printanseditdate}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \bibstring{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printnames{ansp}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{anspid}%
}

\newbibmacro*{stackexchangesite}{%
  \printfield{sitetopic}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{stackexchange}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangequestion}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeask}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeans}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangesite}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}



\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:stackexchange}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangequestion}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeask}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangeans}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{stackexchangesite}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@stackexchange{se:l3help,
  sitetopic = {tex},
  title   = {What can \textit{I} do to help the \LaTeX3 Project},
  askdate = {2012-02-26},
  askid   = {45838},
  askp    = {Brent Longorough},
  askpid  = {344},
  ansp    = {Frank Mittelbach},
  anspid  = {10109},
  ansdate = {2012-03-01},
  ansid   = {46427},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{se:l3help}
ipsum\autocite{sigfridsson}
Lorem\autocite{se:l3help}
ipsum\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As mentioned in the comments `\DeclareBibliographyAlias{cite:stackexchange}{stackexchange}` might be cheaper than having to copy the entire driver definition if they are the same, but I believe there are subtle differences between citations and references in Chicago style, so you may have to have two independent declarations after all.