# Using mymath.sty

Tags: packages, installing, ubuntu

When executing pdflatex I get "File mymath.sty" not found.

I did

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install opencv-doc
```

and

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

but the problem remains.
How can I get my TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) in ubuntu 18.04 to use this package?
Looking at similar cases #43108 and #102817 in tex.stackexchange did not help me.

The file mymath.sty is existing in the following folder. Do I have to do something "by hand"?

```
./usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/html/mymath.sty
```

Comment: The simplest would be to install it in `\texmflocal\tex\latex`.

Comment: @Bernard: How? Can I copy the file manually there and then execute `sudo mktexlsr`? (Sorry from a beginner.)

Comment: Normally, TeX Live installs a `\texmflocal` (or `localtexmf`, I'm not sure) in which one has to install all additions to the distribution that can be available to all users of your computer. The contents of this directory has to respect the t.d.s. structure.

Comment: @Bernard E. g.  `amsmath.sty` is located here `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath`

Comment: You should *never* install your own files in the main TeX directory tree, say, `/usr/local/texlive/2017/`. Does your system feature a directory called `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`?

Comment: @Mico Under `/usr/local` I have the folders `bin  etc  games  include  lib  man  sbin  share  src` . I have a normal `ubuntu 18.04` installation and `texlive 2017` and everything is running fine -- with exception of `mymath.sty` I am using TexMaker.

Comment: @Mico `whereis latex` gives
`latex: /usr/bin/latex  /usr/share/man/man1/latex.1.gz`

Comment: Special case of [packages - Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te?noredirect=1&lq=1) although there may be a better solution specific to OpenCV etc.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by moving file `mymath.sty` from `/usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/html/mymath.sty` to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mymath` (after creating the subfolder `mymath`) and running `sudo mktexlsr`.

Comment: The directory you have chosen is the main distribution directory.  Your file will disappear when you update with a new distribution.

Comment: @barbara beeton What can I do then to use package `mymath`? The point is that I've installed `opencv-doc` since this is mentioned on `https://packages.ubuntu.com/` when searching for `mymath`. But after this the package is not being recognized.

Comment: It's recommended to use a "local" tree parallel to `tex-dist`.  This question [Local texmf tree vs. `TEXINPUTS`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12363) gives some useful information, but is directed to Windows.  [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117522) is specific to *nix.

Comment: Also, better to avoid alter the Primary folders, it's always high risk