# apacite with newapa in spanish (apacite + newapa en español)?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, spanish

I was using `apacite` in Spanish, but I had a problem because instead of "et al" used to appear something like "y cols." which was wrong.

After looking at another answer, I've found that if I use:

```
%
\usepackage[bibnewpage]{apacite}
\begin{document}

Text and citations

\bibliography{biblio} 
\bibliographystyle{newapa}
\end{document}
%%
```

I get the "et al." like it has to be used. Now the problem is that instead of having "Martínez y Pérez (2010)", LaTeX gives me "Martínez & Pérez (2010)".

I've tried with

```
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{y}% Letra que va entre los autores en las referencias
\renewcommand{\BBAB}{y}% Entre autores en el texto
```

but it's not working, or maybe I don't know where to write those commands...

Please help me, it's for my master thesis!

Comment: Hello again! 

I've solvet it!!

Comment: It's just kind of tricky cause windows didn't allowed me to make any changes to "spanish.apc" but I finally just erase the original spanish.apc with my own spanish.apc modified and that was all.

Comment: This is not the right way to solve the problem.  I've added an example to show what you should do.

Answer (score 7):

You should *never* remove or modify the system versions of LaTeX packages, for a few reasons.

- TeX distributions have a method for overriding the system packages without having to disturb the system files, so it's never necessary to do so.
- Any change you make to a system version of a style file will be erased if you update your system.
- If you don't know what you're doing, your changes to a system file may break things.

For more information on how to set up a local folder using MikTeX, see these questions:

- [Texmf tree with MikTeX + Vista32?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12338/2693)
- [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/2693)

That being said, the problem you have doesn't require changing the `.apc` file at all, but instead just making sure that `apacite` knows that you are using Spanish, and renewing the command for the `et al.` text, and using the correct bibliography style for `apacite` (which is `apacite`, *not* `newapa`.)

Since this is for a thesis (and the apacite package is not being required  by a particular journal) you might also consider using `biblatex` and the `biblatex-apa` package, which is a very up-to-date implementation of the APA 6th edition.  There are plenty of examples of its use on the site.

Here is a sample document that shows how to solve your problem correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} % This is the style you should use with `apacite`.

% The following code generates a demonstration bib file
% This part is not needed in your actual document
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 

@article{suner1988,
    Author = {Margarita {Su\~ner} and Mar\`ia {Y\'epez} and Bill Smith and Fred Jones and Joe Doe and Henry Ford},
    Journal = {A Fake Journal},
    Pages = {511-519},
    Title = {The Title of the Paper},
    Volume = {19},
    Year = {1988}}
\end{filecontents} 
% This is the end of the demonstration .bib file
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{et al.\hbox{}}
\cite{suner1988}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

When using:

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

I runned into the same problem. Using only:

```
\renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{et al.\hbox{}}
```

as posted before did not solve the problem. However, the following code worked fine for me:

```
\addto\captionsspanish{
   \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{et al.\hbox{}}
}
```

I also had to redefine many section names to comply with our thesis format, e.g.:

```
\addto\captionsspanish{
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{INDICE GENERAL}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{
 \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{INDICE DE FIGURAS}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{
 \renewcommand{\listtablename}{INDICE DE TABLAS}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{
 \renewcommand{\chaptername}{CAPITULO}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{
\renewcommand{\refname}{BIBLIOGRAFIA}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{
 \renewcommand{\bibname}{}
}
\addto\captionsspanish{
 \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{et al.\hbox{}}
}
```