# export Tikz figures to PDF

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am in the process of writing my master thesis and i am using Tikz to generate few graphs. Unfortunately, the input file for the graphs are not so small, so i already faced the problem that space limitation (solved). Nevertheless, it will take a long time to generate those plots.

My question is whether it is possible to save the generated Tikz figures into a file and to load the file instead? Since the problem is always that the labels do not have the right font size…

PS.

I am using scrbook and pdflatex, I would have no problem to change to something else if it will solve my problem.

Comment: take a look at the `externalize` library in the pgf manual. It does exactly what you need. It will not be in one file, however that can easily be done afterwards.

Comment: Have a look at ['Standalone' TikZ pictures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32127/standalone-tikz-pictures), which seems to be the same basic question. I can recommend you the `standalone` class to create PDF versions of your TikZ pictures, see e.g. [How should I organise my document/files in order to easily export TikZ figures as images?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/how-should-i-organise-my-document-files-in-order-to-easily-export-tikz-figures-a) or [TikZ to non-PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13349) (which besides the name also works for PDFs).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do this with the TikZ library `external`. It saves each picture in an external file, which has a proper graphics format. From now on TikZ will read the external file unless you tell it to regenerate the external file.

There are several methods that regenerate the external graphics files. For example, by setting the TikZ key `external/force remake` at the start of your document, you tell TikZ to regenerate subsequent external pictures. You may set the key as follows: `tikzset{external/force remake}`. Other methods, including methods that use Makefiles, are explained in Section 32.4.3 of the `pgf` manual.

The following is shamelessly copied from the TikZ manual.

*Note: You have to run LaTeX with `shell-escape` enabled.*

```
\documentclass{article}
% main document, called main.tex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activate!
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
A simple image is \tikz \fill (0,0) circle(5pt);.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not quite true. Even if the picture has changed, you have to ask for the figure to be remade. TikZ will happily assume that anything with the right file name is up to date unless you do, for example by using `\tikzset{external/force remake}`.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt Thanks. I'll change the text.

Comment: by setting tikzset{external/force remake}, will it force it to generate the pdf files each time? or only in case of a change?

Comment: @Eagle It will do it for every `tikzpicture` in the current group. By putting the picture in a group and enforcing `external/force remake` at the start of the group, you can restrict the scope of the regeneration to the pictures inside the group.

Comment: @Eagle I should have added _after the `\tikzset{external/force remake}`_ at the end of the first sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: ... but it will do it on each compilation run when that option is set.  In a document with lots of pictures, I use the `external/remake next` key just before the one I'm currently working on and then delete it when I'm happy.  Note that if you don't specify names for your pictures then they are named numerically and so if you insert a new picture not at the end, you'll have to regenerate the lot.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yes it will do it each compilation run. You can also restrict the scope of the remaking to a group, which may be nicer.

Comment: I like to keep a commented out force remake with every TikZ picture. Whenever I need to regenerate one I uncomment it.

Comment: @Mark A better idea may avoiding relying on commenting. I haven't implemented this yet, but it's the next thing I'll do. I'll define a global mechanism that can turn all external picture generation on. The mechanism depends on a `draft`/`final` mode. In `draft` mode, generation is turned off, unless you explicitly say so. In `final` mode, all pictures will be generated. Switches for the `draft` mode may be defined to turn generation on or off. Since I use my own class files, this requires little configuration in the top-level document.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: If you want to regenerate them all then just comment/uncomment `\tikzset{external/force remake}` in the preamble.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Now what would make my day is a routine that runs a checksum of the code in a TikZ picture and compares it with the previous run (may need two compilations). Then it could automatically rebuild when a change is made.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt Using comments makes it impossible to drive the compilation by an external command. With my approach it is possible, which is convenient.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt Checksums aren't completely reliable. I don't know the exact possibilities, but I'd write the body of each `tikzpicture` to a separate external file, compare them with the previous version and only regenerate the external picture files if the bodies differ. Of course I'd also update the save `tikzpicture` bodies.

Comment: Warning: when tikzpictures are given by **macros** `external` it is useless :-( From the TikZ manual Sec. 33.2 page 399: "It CAN'T expand macros during this step, so the only requirement is that every picture's end is directly reachable from its beginning, without further macro expansion."

Comment: Related practical question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577684/).

Comment: Is it possible to generate the figure-pdf as cropped instead of a complete single page?

Answer (score 6):

If you are on Windows or Linux you can use [QtikZ](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/), a dedicated TikZ editor that offers live compilation of your TikZ code and export to PDF and other formats.

You can also consider the [standalone](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package to generate PDF compiling your TikZ code alone with `pdflatex`.

Finally, TikZ offers the `external` library to generate PDFs during the first compilation of your main file (chapter 32 of the [manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)).

Comment: latexit does much the same on OS-X

Comment: When I tried downloading the QtikZ 0.10 installer for Windows, my Windows Defender told me it is malware (contains a trojan).

Answer (score 1):

You can try a semi graphical tikz editor [Tikzedt](http://code.google.com/p/tikzedt/) which I feel has many features like creating pdf file and standalone files.

Comment: NOTE: "TikzEdt is currently (regrettably) only natively available for Windows" (http://www.tikzedt.org/ stand: 26.10.16)