# tikz-feynman and standalone

Tags: tikz-external, tikz-feynman

Unfortunately, tikz-feynman forces the use of LuaLatex to compile. However, I can't find a way to produce nice images to use in another document when compiling with LuaLatex. It seems that one cannot use documentclass{standalone} with LuaLatex (['Standalone' TikZ pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32127/standalone-tikz-pictures?noredirect=1&lq=1)). Similarly, the export method proposed in [export Tikz figures to PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44505/export-tikz-figures-to-pdf) also doesn't work. How can I produce a tikz image in one file to include in another one if I'm using LuaLatex to compile the tikz image (and pdflatex to compile the larger file that should include these images)?

Comment: Add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` right before `\documentclass{standalone}`, and it should work.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315025/lualatex-texlive-2016-standalone-undefined-control-sequence/315027#315027 (I assume that is the problem you encountered.)

Comment: If you want to use externalization, you can set `\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}`. Then LuaLaTeX will be called to compile the pictures instead of pdfLaTeX. (See manual vor3.0.1a section 50.4 on page 609.)

Comment: @Torbjørn, thanks that solves it. Indeed that question is the same and already deals with the issue. I think this question should be marked as a duplicate of the question you mentioned (I flagged it as such).