# Save tikz image in a pdf file in Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, overleaf, export

I have a tikz figure in the Overleaf project. I want to export and save the tikz image in a pdf file. I tried using

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activate!
```

as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44508/161646).

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activate!
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This didn't help me, it only created a blank tikz image in the compiled document and I am not sure if an additional command has to be included to export the tikz image to save the tikz figure as a pdf in the overleaf project. I'm basically doing this to generate pdf versions of all images in my manuscript for submission. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: I think you will have to add more information to your problem, since the link you have provided should actually answer your question. You want to add a tikz picture (you have the code?) into a main document? Is `\input{}` and option?

Comment: @Roland I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by \input{}. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `\input{}` is a way to import code into a target file. Explanation see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/224762)

Comment: @Roland Thank you, but my goal here is to export the tikz figure from overleaf tex file in a pdf .

Comment: But this does not make any sense. Just click on menu -> Download -> pdf and you will get your tikz.tex as a pdf file without furhter commands.

Comment: But that downloads the whole of my manuscript and not just the tikz figure

Comment: I do not know what your document looks like, so I do not know what the actual problem ist.

Answer (score 5):

Following the method described above, I presume that you have tried heading over to the 'Logs and output files' at the top of the Overleaf page?

For me this works by the following three steps after compiling the file:

1. The images are saved as individual .pdf files here:

[image]

2. Go to the 'Other logs and files' tab:

[image]

3. Open + save the file.