# Get {standalone} to ignore blocks of text from \input files (e.g., \begin{spacing} and \maketitle)

Tags: include, input, standalone

I've got a number of separate `.tex` files that are all `\documentclass{article}`. I'm inputting these into a `\documentclass{book}` file as chapters. In the `book.tex` file, then, I've got inputs like this:

```
\chapter{Chapter One!}
\input{article}
```

But I want to be able to compile `article.tex` separately when I need to. So in `article.tex`, I've kept the `\begin{spacing}{1.5}`, `\end{spacing}`, and `\maketitle` commands.

Is there any way to have these commands ignored when I compile `book.tex`? The `\standaloneignore` command seems to work only for ignoring things above the `\documentclass` declaration.

Comment: I believe that that files that get input should be using `\documentclass{standalone}`. This will then ignore the preamble in the separate .tex files up until `\begin{document}`.  Martin provides a [good example here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/using-subfiles-package-with-sty-files/12268#12268)

Comment: @PeterGrill: No, sub-files don't have to use the `standalone` class. It is only required if you want to crop them automatically. Just use `standalone` *package* in the main document and it will remove all preambles independent of the used class in these sub-files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subfile can use either `\documentclass{article}`, or `\documentclass[preview=false]{standalone}`.  The class option `[preview=false]` for the `standalone` package is only there as you want the `article.tex` to compile by itself as it normally would.  You could also use `\documentclass{article}` in the subfile, but the should also add `\usepackage{standalone} \standalonetrue` or `\newif\ifstandlone \standalonetrue`.

If there is specfic code `\begin{document}` in `article.tex` that you don't want processed use the `\ifstandalone` switch as shown below

---

In `article.tex`:

```
\documentclass[preview=false]{standalone}

%% If you prefer to use the `article` class, the I would recommend
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{standalone} \standalonetrue

\title{Artcle.tex Title}
\author{Duck Article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\ifstandalone
   \maketitle% Test to ensure that this is not executed in book.tex
\fi

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

---

In `book.tex:`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book.tex Title}
\author{Duck Book}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle Comment this out to ensure that that \maketitle form the article.tex does not get exectuted.
\chapter{Chapter One}
\input{article}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To use `\ifstandalone` is the correct answer, but your examples aren't that good. You should add `\ifstandalone` in the `article.tex` file and add the mentioned `preview=false` option. Using the `standlone` class is only requiered here to get the `\ifstandalone` switch, but `\documentclass{article} \newif\ifstandlone \standalonetrue` would also do it.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. Have revised per your suggestions.