# bibtex + standalone: How can I include bibliographies in the individual docs *and* the main doc?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, standalone

I'm trying to work on individual sections of a paper separately.  In order to do this, I need to wrap the text in

```
\begin{document}
...
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

The main file looks similar:

```
\begin{document}
\include{A}
\include{B}
...
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

However, with the bibliography included in the sub-file *and* the main file, I end up with these errors: `Illegal, another \bibstyle command`, `Illegal, another \bibdata command`.  I think, had the builds worked, I would also have a duplicate bibliography.

So, the question: How can I keep the individual sub-documents compileable (with bibliography), but also have the "main" document compile with a working bibliography?

Comment: Don't put \begin{document} in your section files, to process just section B add `\includeonly{B}` and then process the main file.

Comment: Unfortunately, that breaks my workflow - I need to be editing document B and building it in the same editor window (I'm using macvim + skim).  Switching to the "main" file and editing it really is not a reasonable option (and right now, it's just as easy to comment out the bibliography in `B` as to add `includeonly` to the main file).

Comment: Could you please rephrase the title so that it builds a real phrase. To have some full [minimal working examples (MWEs)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) incl. the `\documentclass` and minimal required packages would be create. I for example can't see at the moment if you are really using the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) bundle as your title and tags suggest or not. If so, you can use the `\ifstandalone` switch around the `\bibliography{bib}` command.

Comment: create -> great?   Anyway, fixed title.  I have `\usepackage{standalone}` in a `preface.tex` included in the main & sub documents.  The `\ifstandalone` switch sounds very much like what I want; this post helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29995/get-standalone-to-ignore-blocks-of-text-from-input-files-e-g-beginspacin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) bundle here then you can use the `\ifstandalone` switch around the `\bibliography{..}` command to ignore it if the sub-file is compiled as part of the main document. This switch is set to `\iftrue` by the `standalone` class, but to `\iffalse` by the `standalone` package in the main document. See the [`standalone`](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/standalone) package manual for more details.

```
% Subfile e.g. "A.tex"
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
...
\ifstandalone
\bibliography{bib}
\fi
\end{document}
```

```
% main document
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\include{A}
\include{B}
...
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```