# Compile tex dependency before compiling main file

Tags: compiling, pdfpages, combine

I need to include a letter in my report, and I'm doing this using the `pdfpages` package.  I'd like it so that when my report, `report.tex` goes to compile and include `letter.pdf`, it first compile `letter.tex` and then, after having compiled `letter.tex`, include `letter.pdf` into the report.  I've thought of writing a script to do this, but the solution needs to be cross-platform (the report is being worked on by five people using both Linux and Windows).

Thanks.

Comment: Write two version of script, for both Linux and Windows..

Comment: Related Approaches http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multidoc and [Make a .tex file that combines complete .tex documents in subdirectories](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21997/15717) and if possible try `\include{}` and `\input{}`

Comment: This might be a duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122756/including-tex-files-that-need-a-different-style-file-than-the-main-text

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this using `--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18` for `pdflatex` (Assuming your `letter-test.tex` files are safe to run) and `\immediate\write18{...}`

`letter-test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is the letter.
\end{document}
```

`report-test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{mwe} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe
\immediate\write18{pdflatex letter-test}
\begin{document}
This is the report with figure.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\includepdf{letter-test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) to do this instead of a script

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
    \clearpage
    \includepdf[pages={-}]{docA.pdf}

    \clearpage
    \includepdf[pages={-}]{docB.pdf}

    \clearpage
    \includepdf[pages={-}]{docC.pdf}
\end{document}

% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ docA.tex ] }
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ docB.tex ] }
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ docC.tex ] }
% arara: pdflatex
```

I go one step further and have written an `arara` rule which calls `arara`. The `arara` directives in my main document looks like

```
% arara: arara: { files: [ docA.tex ] }
% arara: arara: { files: [ docB.tex ] }
% arara: arara: { files: [ docC.tex ] }
% arara: pdflatex
```

while the directives in `docA.tex` might look like

```
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ docA.tex ] }
% arara: biber: { files: [ docA.bcf ] }
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ docA.tex ] }
% arara: pdflatex: { files: [ docA.tex ] }
```

Comment: +1 for `arara`, however: is it part of TexLive / MikTex? I kind of doubt that the average Windows user will be able to install and use it.

Comment: @Daniel it is included with TexLive and installation on [MikTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100318/how-to-install-arara-with-miktex-windows) doesn't seem that hard. Running it is no harder than running `pdflatex` from the CLI and some LaTeX editors will let you add it as a shortcut.