# Subfiles errors while using style in the main file

Tags: paths, subfiles

I would like to build a modular document in latex. My main directory (in which I put the main file "thesis.tex") is called "tesi". Inside "tesi" i have another directory named "capitoli" where I woluld like to store my chapters named "chapter1.tex","chapter2.tex", and so on. Also I woluld like to compile either from my main file or directly from my subfiles, and so I used the subfile package.

Also I'm using a style file named mystyle.sty placed in the main directory "tesi".
There is also a directory called "immagini" (where i store my images) inside the main directory.

If I use the following code

```
% main file "thesis.tex" in the main directory "tesi" %
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{./tesi/mystyle.sty}
\begin{document}
\subfile{../tesi/capitoli/chapter1.tex}
\end{document}

% subfile "chapter1.tex" in the subdirectory "capitoli" %
\documentclass[../thesis.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{../immagini/image1.jpg}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I can compile from subfile "chapter1.tex" but can't compile from main file "thesis.tex"  (error messages refers to the path of the image files)

If I use the following code ( just changed the relative/absolute paths of mystyle.sty and image1.jpg)

```
% main file "thesis.tex" in the main directory "tesi" %
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{../tesi/mystyle.sty}
\begin{document}
\subfile{../tesi/capitoli/chapter1.tex}
\end{document}

% subfile "chapter1.tex" in the subdirectory "capitoli" %
\documentclass[../thesis.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{./immagini/image1.jpg}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I can't compile from subfile "chapter1.tex" (error message cannot find mystyle.sty) but can compile from main file "thesis.tex".

Someone could fix this issue, thanks.

### Edit

I also post mystyle.sty

```
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
   \usepackage[italian]{babel} 
   \usepackage{subfiles}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: You mix in your explanation "chapter1.txt" and "chapter1.tex". Is chapter1  a `tex` or a `txt` file?

Comment: Do you really need the `mystyle.sty`. Without this, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Clément it's chapter1.tex

Comment: @LaRiFaRi it's just for having a clean main file

Comment: … and I think you are right. Could the answer*s* provided at [Using subfiles package with .sty files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/using-subfiles-package-with-sty-files?rq=1) could be of any help to you ?

Comment: @Clément I've tried but seems not working for me

Comment: @user51020 Yes it works. Please see the edit in my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as this is not possible. You could report this behaviour to the maintainer of the `subfiles` package. The problem is that `subfiles` misinterprets your paths. In my opinion, you are having three options here:

**1.** You may omit the `mystyle.sty` and copy your header in the `thesis.tex`.

> tesi/thesis.tex

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\subfile{capitoli/chapter1.tex}

Test for main file
\end{document}
```

> tesi/capitoli/chapter1.tex

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[../thesis.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{./immagini/image1.jpg}
\end{figure}

Test for subfile
\end{document}
```

**2.** Or you have to make a copy of your most recent `mystyle.sty` into the folder `tesi/capitoli` and keep it actual (shortcuts do not work).

In this case it would look like:

> tesi/thesis.tex

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\subfile{capitoli/chapter1.tex}

Test for main file
\end{document}
```

and the `chapter1.tex` just as in my first example.

**3.** A third possibility would be, to omit your folder `tesi/capitoli` and to put all chapters in the `tesi` folder.

**Edit**

As pointed out by Steve B in [his answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48170) (thanks to Clément for linking that in his comment), you could omit the problem by putting the `thesis.tex` into a lower folder level as well.

> tesi/main/thesis.tex

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{../main/mystyle}
\begin{document}
\subfile{../capitoli/chapter1.tex}

Test for main file
\end{document}
```

> tesi/capitoli/chapter1.tex

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[../main/thesis.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{../immagini/image1.jpg}
\end{figure}

Test for subfile
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would definitely go for this last option: move your main file to a main folder, leave the rest as it.

Comment: Ok, nice didn't understand that I should move also my main files in a subdirectory...with relative path now it works. Thank you yery much.