# Modular Documents \includegraphics file not found

Tags: texlive, paths, includegraphics

I'm starting a Modular Latex project for the first time and I'm having problems with adding figures. I'm using the `\input{}` command to add files to the main `documento.tex` as in the Latex/Modular Documents Wiki, but when I compile, there's this error message

> ! LaTeX Error: File `img/imgfuv2018Din1' not
>   found.

I already tried to use the `subfiles` package and follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367799/problem-with-includegraphics-file-not-found/367805), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187752/subfiles-errors-while-using-style-in-the-main-file) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/using-subfiles-package-with-sty-files) suggestions, but neither of them worked

My project structure is like this

```
./documento.tex
./estilo.sty
./tex/
./img/
```

The `documento.tex` is

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{estilo}
\graphicspath{{img/},{..img/}}

\begin{document}

\input{tex/fuv2018_din_1}

\end{document}
```

and `fuv2018_din_1.tex` is

```
example text
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/imgfuv2018Din1}
```

Even when I put the `\includegraphics` command in the `documento.tex` or when I put the `imgfuv2018Din1` file in the same directory it gives me the same error.

I use TexLive version 6.2.1. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: the `estilo.sty` is a custom style file and I followed wiki's suggestion and is the following:

```
\ProvidesPackage{estilo}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: The tex file inside the tex directory is trying to find the image file in a img directory within the tex directory, which of course doesn't exist (at least, that's my diagnostic). I hope that made sense. You could put your tex files in the same root directory as the main tex file. Or put the img directory (as a test) inside the tex directory

Comment: And welcome to tex.sx!

Comment: `..img/` is a strange path.  I assume you mean `../img/`.  But it should work without that line.  I'm not familiar with `estilo`.  Is it a custom style file?  I would not recommend that for a first project.  Regardless, does `estilo` have its own `\usepackage{graphicx}`?

Comment: which extension do your graphics have? And how are you compiling? With pdflatex?

Comment: Hi. I tried putting the img folder inside the tex folder, putting the `fuv2018_din_1.tex` and images on the same folder as the main `documento.tex`, changing the path to `../img/`, and also putting the packages directly on the main file, but it still returns the same error. 
The graphics are PNG files and I'm compiling with PDFLaTeX, using Texmaker (also tried to compile in the terminal, but it's the same).