# subfile not working at all

Tags: subfiles

So after reinstalling Miktex I can't use subfiles anymore. Anytime `\subfile{insert file}` is referenced, this error pops up

```
! LaTeX Error: File `main.toc' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: toc)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop
```

This appears in both texmaker and texstudio, and I can compile my files fine on Overleaf, so I believe it's a Miktex issue. Reinstalled, same problem appears. If a table of content is not signified, the error turns into `main.out not found`, or `.out` or `.aux` for the most barebone of subfile usage example. The document compiles fine if `\subfile{insert file}` is removed. No idea what happened.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! Any clue when there's gonna be a permanent fix for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using subfiles package with .sty files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/using-subfiles-package-with-sty-files)

Comment: @pband1256 oh I expect Donald will upload to ctan in a day or so, but note if you use texlive 2019 it's frozen so you would need an update from ctan by hand

Comment: Uploaded import.sty v 6.1 to CTAN now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you manage to solve it?